# Find the largest value from column using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using SQL where I have column having values like

```
A B
X1 2 4 6 8 10
X2 2 33 44 56 78 98 675 891 11111
X3 2 4 672 234 2343 56331
X4 51 123 232 12 12333
```

I want a query to get the value from col B with col A which has max count of values. I.e output should be

```
x2  2 33 44 56 78 98 675 891 11111
```

Query I use:

```
select max(B) from table
```

Results in

```
51 123 232 12 12333
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: What is the structure of your database table, i.e. is column B defined as VARCHAR or something else?

Comment: Sample data A B
x1 2 4 6 8 10
x2 2 33 44 56 78 98 675 891 11111
x3 2 4 672 234 2343 56331
x4 51 123 232 12 12333

Comment: **Don't** store multiple values in a single field. Put them as individual records into another table and use the `PK` of the original table as `FK` into the new table.

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: yes both columns are varchar2(255) type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both columns are strings, and that column `B` uses single space for separators and no leading/trailing spaces, you can use this approach:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DESC LENGTH(B)-LENGTH(REPLACE(B, ' ', ''))
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

The heart of this solution is `LENGTH(B)-LENGTH(REPLACE(B, ' ', ''))` expression, which counts the number of spaces in the string `B`.

**Note:** `FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY` is Oracle-12c syntax. For earlier versions use `ROWNUM` approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25032327/335858).

Answer (score 1):

In case there is more than one separating space or more then one row meets criteria do this: count number of spaces (or groups of spaces) in each row using `regexp_count()`. Use `rank` to find most (groups of) spaces. Take only rows ranked as `1`:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/EYILJ18961)</sup>**

```
select *
  from (select t.*, rank() over (order by regexp_count(b, ' +') desc) rnk from t)
  where rnk = 1
```