# when i press the button it always duplicate the existing records on the jTable

Tags: java, netbeans

When I press the button it always duplicates the existing records on the jTable. How can I show just one data at a time?

```
void showAll(){
    try{
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ATTENDANCE");
        while (rs.next()){
            String a1 = rs.getString("NAME");
            String b1 = rs.getString("COURSE");
            String c1 = rs.getString("STUDENTNO");
            String d1 = rs.getString("DATE");
            DB1.addRow(new Object[]{a1,b1,c1,d1});
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Iif I understand correctly problem related with your  query so you can look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919481/how-to-select-only-1-row-from-oracle-sql

Comment: Why have you use `rs` and then `rs1`? Is it a typo?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yess its just a typo sorry

Comment: @User8500049 nope :(

Comment: It's not clear what you want, the code that you present shows selecting all data in the table and add to DB1. Could you please provide more details

Comment: @am0awad  i only wanted to be selected is the last data that i input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
String query = "SELECT a.* FROM ATTENDANCE a WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(aa.id) FROM ATTENDANCE aa);"
```

, or

```
String query = "SELECT a.* FROM ATTENDANCE a WHERE id=(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())";
```