# Oracle: An elegant way to take the first n record (top-k query)

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's assume we want to take the first 1 record of a resultset. Is there a more elegant way to do it?

```
   WITH temp
        AS (  SELECT WKFC_CRONOLOGIA_ID
                FROM SIUWKF.WKF_CRONOLOGIA c
               WHERE     Ogg_oggetto_id = vOGG_ID
                     AND TOG_TIPO_OGGETTO_ID = vTOG
                     AND C.WKFC_DATA_FIN = TO_DATE ('31/12/9999', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                     AND Wkfc_Tipo = 'STATO'
            ORDER BY WKFC_DATA_INI DESC)
   SELECT WKFC_CRONOLOGIA_ID
     INTO vCRONOLOGIA_ID
     FROM temp
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think there is any other elegant way to do it. There may be other ways to do it, but those will not necessarily be elegant anyways.

Comment: Which are other way to formulate top-k query?

Comment: what are you trying to avoid with what you have?  or what...... about the current query is "not elegant"?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451534/how-to-do-top-1-in-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is alright. The only other solution with Oracle is to use the `row_number()` analytical function but this makes it less elegant. Other databases have the `TOP 1` statement but there is no other Oracle equivalent to it than `ROWNUM` outside a subquery when you have an `ORDER BY` in use. I agree to use `WITH` which makes it more readable. The following might be written faster but I am not sure if it is more elegant. Maybe a matter of taste:

```
SELECT * FROM
(  SELECT WKFC_CRONOLOGIA_ID
                FROM SIUWKF.WKF_CRONOLOGIA c
               WHERE     Ogg_oggetto_id = vOGG_ID
                     AND TOG_TIPO_OGGETTO_ID = vTOG
                     AND C.WKFC_DATA_FIN = TO_DATE ('31/12/9999', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                     AND Wkfc_Tipo = 'STATO'
            ORDER BY WKFC_DATA_INI DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

This is what Oracle SQL manual says about `ROWNUM` and top-N reporting and confirms your way in doing it.

[image]

Source Oracle® Database
SQL Language Reference
11g Release 2 (11.2)
E26088-01

Comment: How could you rewrite using analytical function?