# SELECT * WHERE val = MIN ( val )?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, minimum

I'm fairly new to Oracle SQL, but already it's logic is beginning to confuse me. I'm trying to select all columns from a table where a particular column PRICE has the minimum value.

This works:

```
SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM my_tab;
```

This returns me the minimum value. But why can't I select all the columns in that row? The following won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tab WHERE PRICE = MIN( PRICE );
```

What am I missing here? Cheers folks!

****EDIT****

Here is the full code I'm having trouble with:

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT c.NAME, o.* FROM customers c JOIN customer_orders o ON c.CUST_NBR = o.CUST_NBR ) AS t WHERE t.PRICE = ( SELECT MIN( t.PRICE) FROM t );

Comment: You can't use an aggregate in the where clause of a select statement.  That is a syntax error.

Comment: It's not unique to Oracle - it's common to most implementations of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM TABLE)

--Edited 

WITH 
TABLE AS 
(QUERY) 
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE PRICE = (SELECT MIN(PRICE) FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The table I'm selecting from is already from a select statement. Will that cause a problem? I posted my code in a comment already but for some reason it was removed

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a subquery to get the result:

```
select t1.*
from my_tab t1
inner join
(
  SELECT MIN(PRICE) MinPrice
  FROM my_tab
) t2
  on t1.price = t2.minprice
```

Answer (score 0):

See previous SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451534/how-to-do-top-1-in-oracle), and especially answer by "Vash" which is best for your purposes. Note that you probably want to avoid a subselect since Oracle may be smart enough to use an index on the price if available to look at only one record.

Most databases, but apparently not Oracle, have either `TOP 1` or `LIMIT` clauses for questions like these.