# Grab max only from today's data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of data that looks like this. Is there a way to only grab the max value from today's date without using a where statement?

I was using the script below but it seems to conflict and gets me all the timestamps and the highest value from each `timestamp`. If someone knows a way to select the max value from today in one/two lines that would be great. Thank you

```
Select timestamp,
       max(value)
  FROM Table1
 WHERE r.timestamp > ( ( SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00',
                                           'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) 
                        * 24 * 60 * 60) - 57600; 


 TIMESTAMP      VALUE
---------- ----------
1359574942          1
1359574942         12
1359575012          0
1359575012          0
1359575122          9
1359575212          0
```

Comment: Why can't you use a where statement?

Comment: If I use this where statement i would get multiple values base on timestamp. I just want the max value from this range of time.

Comment: Just remove the `timestamp,` from the SELECT statement in your query and you will get the max value as you expect.

Comment: I NEED the timestamp. That is the whole point of the question. Of course it is going to work if you just do a select max value.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the max value of today, all you need is

```
select max(value) 
from table1
where timestamp > trunc(systimestamp);
```

If your table can have data for the future (timestamp>systimestamp),

```
select max(value) 
from table1
where timestamp > trunc(systimestamp)
      and timestamp < trunc(systimestamp) + 1;
```

A quick solution to get the corresponding timestamp as well,

```
select * from (
    select timestamp, max(value) m
    from table1
    where ts > trunc(systimestamp)
    group by timestamp
    order by m desc
) where rownum < 2;
```

See [How to do top 1 in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451534/how-to-do-top-1-in-oracle) for other possible options.

Comment: I need the timestamp and when it occur as well. The timestamp is the part giving me the problem. The data is useless without the time it occured.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just need to include a `HAVING` clause to your query to only get rows with equal to  time stamp of the current day.

```
SELECT r.timestamp,
       max(r.value)
  FROM Table1 r
 WHERE r.timestamp > ( ( SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) * 24 * 60 * 60) - 57600 
GROUP BY r.timestamp
HAVING r.timestamp = <timestamp-for-today>
```

Note: You need to fix the `<timestamp-for-today>` in the HAVING clause. I'm not quite sure what the calculation for that is (I didn't put much time into figuring that out).

Comment: OP needs the TS corresponding to the max value, this gives the max value corresponding to the max TS.

Comment: @Nivas You're right. I did include a comment that the HAVING clause could filter for the timestamp of the current day.  I've corrected the query. Thanks for the quality review :)

Comment: :-). BTW, `timestamp-for-today` is `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP)` depending on whether you want only the date part  (date and 00:00:00.0000) or the time part (current instant)