# How can I retrieve next n unlocked rows from Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have Oracle table `books` store n books info with columns `id` and `title`. Some of the tuples are locked by `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` clause.

Suppose these rows whose id in (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9) are get locked.

Now I want to write a SQL to achieve that when execute it, return the ***next*** 2 records which are unlocked. And the SQL may be called by multiple process at same time.

That is to say, the first call will return id = 3 and id = 7 records; the second call will return id = 8 and id = 10 records.

I think `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` would help, it auto skips rows which are locked and solved the multiple process call at same time problem. But how to achieve get ***next*** 2 records? I don't think [rownum](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) works, because I do not know which rows are locked.

Could anybody share your ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you proved that using a rownum predicate would not work?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, indeed. Because you do not know which rows are locked, so cannot use `rownum` to restrict.

Comment: that sounds like a deduction rather than an actual test, though. I didn't see any documentation that said that rownum and skip locked wouldn't work.

Comment: "skip locked" is applied after the rownum filter, so if you supplied a rownum which was locked, the query would return 0 rows unless a wait clause was specified.

Answer (score 1):

In 12c you can use the row_limiting_clause, documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

The general syntax is:

```
[ OFFSET offset { ROW | ROWS } ]
[ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ { rowcount | percent PERCENT } ]
    { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES } ]
```

Alternatively, use the Oracle Streams Advanced Queuing API documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADQUE/aq_opers.htm#ADQUE2835

Answer (score -2):

I'm no oracle expert (or user even ;)) but might this work? (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29899276/97614)):

```
SELECT * FROM  MYTABLE FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED        
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```