# Extract a single row which is not locked in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, rownum

I have a big dataset in Oracle which I need to process some of the rows which has a column `PROCESSED= 0`.

I have multiple instances of an application which will read 1 row at a time and perform the processing. To avoid multiple threads to access to the same row - I am using

`SELECT *  FROM FOO WHERE ROWNUM = 1 FOR UPDATE`

If I execute the above query, the first thread is locking the row and the other rows are not able to fetch any rows as the `ROWUM = 1` is already locked by the first thread. What I am trying to achieve is to fetch the "**next unlocked**" row.

Is there an efficient way to do it via SQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993756/how-can-i-retrieve-next-n-unlocked-rows-from-oracle
Does this help?

Comment: Rownum won't work because it is arbitrary - values are assigned when the query runs and apply only to the result set, not the order of the rows in the table itself.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **SKIP LOCKED** is what are you looking for.
See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702)

```
select * from foo for update skip locked
```

will select only those rows which are not locked by other transactions