# ORA-00904: "RN": Invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone please explain to me why I'm getting this error, where I'm wrong and what to do in future to avoid it.

```
SELECT a.*, row_number() over (partition by code_employee order by  
to_date(substr(last_located_time,1,10),'yyyy-mm-dd')) rn
FROM
    (SELECT LAST_LOCATED_TIME, NAME_COMMON, CODE_EMPLOYEE
FROM 
     daily_report

 WHERE INSERT_DATE = TRUNC (SYSDATE-3) AND DEVICE_NAME LIKE '%SM-T116IR')a 
 WHERE rn=1;
```

Comment: you can't use a column-alias in the `where` clause.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451534/how-do-i-do-top-1-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

please try this one :

```
select *
  from (select a.*,
               row_number() over(order by to_date(last_located_time, 'dd.mm.rrrr')) rn
          from (select last_located_time, name_common, code_employee
                  from daily_report                
                 where insert_date = trunc(sysdate-3) and device_name like '%SM-T116IR') a)
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: Ozhan thanks for the input.. can somebody plz explain me this query as I'm trying to understand the code written by someone....                
      `row_number() over (partition by code_employee order by  to_date(substr(last_located_time,1,10),'yyyy-mm-dd'))`

Comment: You're welcome Toddler. By the way, you'd better use "substr(to_char(nd_sonokuma,'yyyy-mm-dd'),1,10)" for "order by" clause. Since as you know, "substr" should be applied to a string, not to a date.

Comment: ozhan but the guy used `substr` to `nvarchar2` column and then convert it `to_date` which dosen't make sense to me since he is not using it as date.