# SQL for getting data from the row with the highest version value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with data like this:

```
Id     | Version | isLive
-------+---------+-------
comp1  |   2     | true     
comp1  |   3     | true     
comp1  |   4     | false    
comp1  |   1     | true      
comp2  |   4     | true      
comp2  |   1     | false
```

I want to fetch the row that has the highest version number per ID. So there should only be one row per ID.

```
select id 
from mytable 
group by id
```

This returns the data randomly.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451569/11005027)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTbl ORDER BY version ) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
         select id,max(distinct version) from 
         mytable 
        group by id order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SQL> with test (id, version, islive) as
  2    (select 'comp1', 2, 'true'  from dual union all
  3     select 'comp1', 3, 'true'  from dual union all
  4     select 'comp1', 4, 'false' from dual union all
  5     select 'comp1', 1, 'true'  from dual union all
  6     select 'comp2', 4, 'true'  from dual union all
  7     select 'comp2', 1, 'false' from dual
  8    )
  9  select id, version, islive
 10  from (select id, version, islive,
 11          row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) rn
 12        from test
 13       )
 14  where rn = 1;

ID       VERSION ISLIV
----- ---------- -----
comp1          4 false
comp2          4 true

SQL>
```