# Oracle query for get employee in and out time for generated query based on first in and lastout

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to get employee attendance based on in/our at my oracle database table column. The column name is Direction which have in/out value and time have at another column. 
my problem is that I am getting in and out time more times for a employee sine they are are do in and out more than one times with their card pance system. I wanted to get only first in time for each employee and last out time for each employee. Here is my query for this

```
select
fullname,direction,to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy  hh12:mi:ss PM') as Time,
gate,lane,employment.employeeid,NATIONALID,departmentname,designation.designationname
from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa
join eofficeuat.employee on entrylog_cpa.hrrecordid=employee.hrrecordid
join eofficeuat.employment on employee.hrrecordid=employment.hrrecordid
join eofficeuat.designation on employment.designationid=designation.designationid
join eofficeuat.department on employment.departmentid=department.departmentid
where department.departmentname = 'SECURITY'
and tstamp >= 1568763700 and tstamp < (select (sysdate - date '1970-01-01') * 86400000 from dual)
order by fullname desc;
```

here is data for the query

```
fullname        Direction   Time
--------        ---------   ----------

Utpal Dhar      In          18-09-2019  08:02:00 AM
Utpal Dhar      In          18-09-2019  08:04:31 AM
Utpal Dhar      In          18-09-2019  08:04:35 AM
TOPAZZAL HOSEN  In          19-09-2019  07:57:51 AM
TOPAZZAL HOSEN  In          18-09-2019  07:56:39 AM
TOPAZZAL HOSEN  out         18-09-2019  04:13:18 PM
TOPAZZAL HOSEN  out         18-09-2019  12:36:23 PM
```

this query giving all in and out time for each employee, but I need only row which will first in time with in direction and last out time with last direction.

Here is rows as I am expecting

```
fullname        Direction   Time
--------        ---------   ----------

Utpal Dhar      In          18-09-2019  08:02:00 AM
TOPAZZAL HOSEN  In          18-09-2019  07:56:39 AM
TOPAZZAL HOSEN  out         18-09-2019  04:13:18 PM
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `analytical function` -- `ROW_NUMBER()` in such a situation:

```
SELECT
    FULLNAME,
    DIRECTION,
    TIME,
    ROUND((MAX_TIME - MIN_TIME)*24, 2) AS DURATION
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            T.*,
            MIN(CASE
                WHEN T.DIRECTION = 'In' THEN TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')
            END) OVER(
                PARTITION BY FULLNAME, TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'))
            ) AS MIN_TIME,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN T.DIRECTION = 'Out' THEN TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')
            END) OVER(
                PARTITION BY FULLNAME, TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'))
            ) AS MAX_TIME
        FROM
            ( YOUR_QUERY ) T
    )
WHERE
    TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM') IN (
        MIN_TIME,
        MAX_TIME
    );
```

Cheers!!

Comment: this showing me this error "ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number."

Comment: Because the time column in your query is not a date, you convert it to date, before using it in outer query. Also, This query will give you day-wise IN and OUT for each employee

Comment: time is stored in my table as unix timestamp. this have in eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa table and I have converted it to to_date at main query

Comment: you are my hero this working but still have some bug like I am getting a employee who have in time but getting out time. Can you please check it again?

Comment: I think same employee name not coming twice, but I need same employee name should be twice with in and out time if have

Comment: You are correct, I have updated the query. Please check now!!

Comment: this returning zero row

Comment: Check the updated answer now!! Case when is added into the WHERE clause

Comment: showing this error "ORA-00904: "T"."DIRECTION": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier""

Comment: That is in WHERE clause, You can remove that (t.) Anyway, Updated the answer

Comment: ok, but I am still getting in time row for a employee not out time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199676/discussion-between-tejash-and-mdkamrul).

Comment: one more help, can i find hours difference between in and out time?

Comment: (date1 - date2) * 24

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I am getting the duration like this https://gyazo.com/2b206a76ba267e0b761bc2c6dc91f562 . please check

Comment: I am not getting this as hours https://gyazo.com/54e23efbc506caa339d67aed116d5fc4

Comment: What is your dates for which 0.61 is showing as an hour?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/58f747cb0b3db06cb42cd627e65c34af here is complete result, the time columns are dates

Comment: I think it is giving correct output. It is difference in hours between out and in time. What is your expectation apart from 0.61?

Comment: my expectation is diffrence between in and out time as hours. here is the two time in = 30-09-2019 01:19:18 PM and out = 30-09-2019 01:55:55 PM
diffrence showing 0.61 . is 0.61 is correct hours?

Comment: Yes,0.61 is correct hours. You can count the minutes using (0.61*60) = 36.6 minutes

Comment: yes but i not getting it correct for all agent like https://gyazo.com/d4452850cc63894f8171a57272870695 . if you see the first two row in = 29-09-2019 12:26:51 PM and out = 29-09-2019 04:15:28 PM 
duration is 228.62 as hours this not making sense by the way I have updated the query at answer

Comment: can you also come on chat please?

Comment: can you let me know please how can calculate total rows returned from this query?

Comment: Use `count(1) over()` after calculation of maxtime and add it in select clause to see total rows which will display total rows count - same number in each row

Comment: can you please tell me how can i merge in and out rows in one row with time so Fullname not will show twice with 2 rows? so should be in one row with in and out time like the image https://gyazo.com/50280e3fdf0fe5d3c6ea535f92608469

Comment: can you please make this solution for me? I also have open a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411584/oracle-query-for-combine-two-rows-data-into-two-columns-data

Answer (score 0):

Order it by time then select the top row use rownum. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451534/how-do-i-do-top-1-in-oracle) is the way you can use.

```
SELECT A.FULLNAME, B.DIRECTION, B.TIME 
FROM eofficeuat.employee A
JOIN (
//YOUR QUERY GOES HERE
select
fullname,direction,to_char(((TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + (tstamp/24/60/60) + 6/24)), 'dd-mm-yyyy  hh12:mi:ss PM') as Time,
gate,lane,employment.employeeid,NATIONALID,departmentname,designation.designationname
from eofficeuat.entrylog_cpa
join eofficeuat.employee on entrylog_cpa.hrrecordid=employee.hrrecordid
join eofficeuat.employment on employee.hrrecordid=employment.hrrecordid
join eofficeuat.designation on employment.designationid=designation.designationid
join eofficeuat.department on employment.departmentid=department.departmentid
where department.departmentname = 'SECURITY'
and tstamp >= 1568763700 and tstamp < (select (sysdate - date '1970-01-01') * 86400000 from dual)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 // the rownum should be here
order by fullname desc;
//YOUR QUERY GOES HERE
) B
ON A.FULLNAME = B.FULLNAME
GROUP BY A.FULLNAME, B.DIRECTION, B.TIME
```

This should work

Comment: if i use rownum = 1 then I am getting only one row.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check if the query should work

Comment: the fullname have in eofficeuat.employee table

this query showing me this error " ORA-00904: "A"."FULLNAME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: I have edit the query in my answer, please check again

Comment: I am still getting one row and just full name column. also can you say what should be at " //your query goes here " comment?

Comment: in the block "//your query goes here" I just copy and paste your query that you put in the question, so basically I just make your query into subquery to join from a table that contain fullname, then filter it with each fullname which contain rownum=1 (only the 1st row for each fullname). For the column you should add another column you need in the main query.

Comment: ok but my query which have in block does not working I meant I am not getting columns and rows as I the query have in block. I am getting only one row and one column which is full name

Comment: I have edit it again, I have mistakenly put the rownum filter. Please check again

Comment: sorry this showing this error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Forgot to add all column described in group by expression. I have add all column now. Should be working now.

Comment: still i am getting only one row