# Oracle query for combine two rows data into two columns data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query which show up vehicle in and out time in one columns with two rows with in and out time. I wanted to show this within one rows as in-time and out-time. Here is my query

```
SELECT 
RowNum as sr,
agent_name,
agency_name,
TO_CHAR(ISSUEDATETIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH12:MI:SS PM') as issueddatetime,
action,
TIME,
gate,
passnumber,
cardnumber,
vehicletype,
(ROUND((MAX_TIME - MIN_TIME)*24, 2))  AS DURATION
FROM
(
      SELECT T.*,
            CASE
            WHEN T.ACTION = 'IN' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY AGENT_ID, TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'))
                ORDER BY
                TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')
            )
            END AS IN_TIME_RN,
            CASE
            WHEN T.ACTION = 'OUT' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY AGENT_ID, TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'))
                ORDER BY TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')
                DESC
            )
            END AS OUT_TIME_RN,

            MIN(CASE
                WHEN T.ACTION = 'IN' THEN TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')
            END) OVER(
                PARTITION BY AGENT_ID, TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')) 
            ) AS MIN_TIME,

            MAX(CASE
                WHEN T.ACTION = 'OUT' THEN TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM')
            END) OVER(
                PARTITION BY AGENT_ID, TRUNC(TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM'))
            ) AS MAX_TIME

      FROM
      (
            SELECT
            eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.agent_id,
            eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_name,
            eofficeuat.gatepass.agency_name,
            eofficeuat.gatepass.agency_id,
            TO_CHAR(eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.scantime, 'dd-mm-yyyy               HH12:MI:SS PM') as Time,            
            eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.action,
            eofficeuat.gatelist.shortname as gate,
            eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber,
            eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.cardnumber,
            eofficeuat.gatepass.vehicletype,
            eofficeuat.gatepass.ISSUEDATETIME
        FROM
            eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle
            INNER JOIN eofficeuat.cnf_agents ON eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.agent_id = eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_id
            INNER JOIN eofficeuat.gatelist ON eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.gate_id = eofficeuat.gatelist.id
            INNER JOIN eofficeuat.gatepass ON eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber = eofficeuat.gatepass.id

        WHERE           
            eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.scantime between TO_DATE ('08/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_DATE ('15/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
            ORDER BY Time asc

      )T
)
    WHERE

    TO_DATE(TIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh12:mi:ss PM') IN (
        MIN_TIME,
        MAX_TIME
    )

    and
    (ROUND((MAX_TIME - MIN_TIME)*24, 2)) is not null

    and
    (ROUND((MAX_TIME - MIN_TIME)*24, 2)) > 0
```

Here is out put for this query

```
  Agency_name        Action      Time
  ===========        =======     ===========================
  Luna Corporation   In          09-10-2019 04:03:06 PM 
  Luna Corporation   Out         09-10-2019 04:32:49 PM
```

But I wanted like this

```
  Agency_name        In                       Out
  ===========        =======                  ======
  Luna Corporation   09-10-2019 04:03:06 PM   09-10-2019 04:03:06 PM
```

so two rows combined to one row with two different column In and out

Comment: Can you show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (Take a look at [mcve] before you start.)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of your logic are needed.  A db fiddle of some sort would help.

Comment: If your requirement is to make two rows into one assuming all other column data is same, Then my approach would be Group by with values and nested query with concatenation for the IN||OUT as one column. Just a thought.

Comment: Your query select many columns, but your specified result has only 3 columns. Either adjust the query, or its result - to match!

Comment: yes will show the columns also in one row, I have only mentioned some of columns

Answer (score 0):

Just my approach, thought might be useful. "The PIVOT operator takes data in separate rows, aggregates it and converts it into columns".
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

```
with   
vechile_log as 
    ( select 'Luna Corporation' as Agency_name, 'IN' as action, 
      to_date('09-10-2019 16:03:06','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')as Tme from dual
      UNION
      select 'Luna Corporation' as Agency_name, 'OUT' as action, 
      to_date('09-10-2019 16:32:49','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as Tme  from dual)
select * from (
             select AGENCY_NAME, --add extra columns here
                    tme, action from vechile_log)
pivot(max(tme) for action in ('IN' , 'OUT' ));
```