# BETWEEN clause versus <= AND >=

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Is there a performance difference between using a BETWEEN clause or using <= AND >= comparisons?

i.e. these two queries:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM table  
 WHERE year BETWEEN '2005' AND '2010';
```

...and

```
SELECT *  
  FROM table  
 WHERE year >= '2005' AND year <= '2010';
```

In this example, the year column is VARCHAR2(4) with an index on it.

Comment: I wouldn't use a string like `'2005'` to filter years or dates, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no performance difference between the two example queries because `BETWEEN` is simply a shorthand way of expressing an *inclusive* range comparison. When Oracle parses the `BETWEEN` condition it will automatically expand out into separate comparison clauses:

ex.

```
SELECT *  
  FROM table
 WHERE column BETWEEN :lower_bound AND :upper_bound
```

...will automatically become:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM table
 WHERE :lower_bound <= column
   AND :upper_bound >= column
```

Comment: @rsenna: No, I posted this question to store the information here because someone in our office asked me this and I noticed when searching that no one else had ever asked it here before. It's my knowledge contribution to the world for the day and is a valid use of the service per the FAQ and mission statement. I intended to ask, answer and accept my answer all within 10 seconds but the system would not let me accept my own answer so quickly so other people started answering too...

Comment: Hey, no problem. In fact SO officially [approves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) such behavior...

Comment: @rsenna: Exactly! :) Thanks for digging up that link, and to further explain the scenario I had forgotten that you have to [wait two days to answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)...

Comment: I personally disagree with the existence of the badge, because all I've ever seen is people trying to game the system to get it (posting the known answer to a duplicate within minutes of posting the question).  Worse is those who accept their own over the people who correctly answered before them.  I'll never enable the behavior by voting for such answers.

Answer (score 34):

There is no difference.

Note that `BETWEEN` is always inclusive and sensitive to the order of the arguments.

`BETWEEN '2010' AND '2005'` will never be `TRUE`.

Comment: Depends on the underlying RDBMS system. SQL-92 says that _"X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z"_ but not all vendors hew to that line. SQL Server, for instance, does not.

Comment: @Nicholas: please look at the question tags. As for you `SQL Server` comment, could you please provide a reference?

Comment: Unless they've tightened things up for between, order is unimportant. Can't say I've tested that recently, though. Having been burned on that before, If order is critical for a test, I make the test explicit test with `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: @Nicholas: are you saying that there was a version of `SQL Server` which evaluated `3 BETWEEN 4 AND 2` as `TRUE`?

Comment: @Nicholas: could you please name this version?

Comment: Couldn't tell you. Might have been SQL Server 2000, might be an earlier version. Just noted it as something to avoid.

Comment: @Nicholas: cannot be `SQL Server 2000`. Neither can it be `SQL Server 4.21` which shared `Sybase` codebase. So it must be `6.0`, `6.5` or `7.0` in which they introduced the standard violation only to fix it again in `2000` (without providing backwards compatibility or even mentioning this behavior in the docs). Not that I doubted you, but this is quite a strange thing to hear about a Microsoft product.

Comment: What? Bugs in a MS product! Surely you jest B^) I should probably not tell you about the code generation bug I found in Visual Studio, that resulted in behaviour changing when optimization was turned on. The code in question was something like `a[++i]=b[j++][i++];` The compiler team refused to fix it on the grounds that it was, according to the C Standard, "implementation-specific" behaviour. Never mind that the actual bug was actually an optimization error: turning on optimization should not result in a **different program**.

Comment: @Nicholas: as I said before, I don't doubt you. It's just strange that you are the only person aware of this bug (which would break lots of code) and even you cannot name the version of the product which introduced the bug.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it depends on your DBMS engine.

Some database management systems will compute twice your expression (once for each comparison), and only once when you use `BETWEEN`.

Actually if the expression can have a non-deterministic result `BETWEEN` will have a different behaviour, compare the following in SQLite:

```
WHERE RANDOM() BETWEEN x AND y -- one random value generated

WHERE RANDOM() >= x AND RANDOM() <= y -- two distinct random values generated
```

This can be very time consuming if your expression is (for example) a subquery.

Comment: Interesting thought... Can you provide an example for this? For what database did you experience that?

Comment: Hmm, good thinking. That leaves some open questions regarding the [SQL standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9680753/521799), and whether it is really possible to claim that the two expressions are equivalent

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt (for Oracle anyway), run an [explain plan](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm) and you'll see what the optimizer wants to do.  This would apply to most questions about "is there a performance difference between ...".  Of course there are a lot of other tools also, but explain plan is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

It **should** be the same.

Good database engine will generate same plan for that expression.

Comment: yes, my comment was more generic than this specific situation.  Teach a man to fish...

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth considering the SQL standard for this (although this *might not* correspond to all implementations, even if it *should*):

```
Format

<between predicate> ::=
  <row value constructor> [ NOT ] BETWEEN
    <row value constructor> AND <row value constructor>

Syntax Rules

[...]

6) "X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z".
```

Having said so, there is no difference in behaviour, although for complex `X`, there may be a difference in parsing time, as mentioned by [Benoit here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4809148/521799)

Found in http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Answer (score 0):

run1 "X>=Y AND X<=Z"

run2 "X BETWEEN Y AND Z"

I get one `Plan hash value` when I run explain plan twice.
But Tom's runStats_pkg get diffent result:

```
Run1 ran in 1 cpu hsecs
Run2 ran in 1 cpu hsecs
run 1 ran in 100% of the time

Name                      Run1    Run2        Diff
STAT...recursive calls          12      13       1
STAT...CPU used by this sessio       2       3       1
STAT...physical read total IO        0       1       1
STAT...consistent gets          18      19       1
...
...
LATCH.row cache objects         44,375   1,121     -43,254
LATCH.cache buffers chains      68,814   1,397     -67,417
STAT...logical read bytes from     655,360     573,440     -81,920
STAT...session uga memory max      123,512       0    -123,512
STAT...session pga memory      262,144  65,536    -196,608
STAT...session pga memory max      262,144  65,536    -196,608
STAT...session uga memory     -327,440  65,488     392,928

Run1 latches total versus runs -- difference and pct
Run1        Run2    Diff       Pct
203,927      28,673    -175,254    711.22%
```

Answer (score 0):

You better check your execution plans because there can be some weird edge cases where `BETWEEN` can have a different execution plan from the standard >= and <= combination.

https://blog.pythian.com/oracle-can-between-and-greater-than-or-equal-to-and-less-than-or-equal-to-differ/

Caveat emptor obviously. But since execution plans can change over time and I really do not have an appetite to test such things, I rather not use BETWEEN at all.

Sometimes less choice  is better.