# Dynamic Select SQL statements with MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

I would like to have dynamic sql statements using mybatis in an Oracle 12g database where I can utilize a hash map to add conditionals something like the following:

```
<select id="getUsers" resultType="hashmap" parameterType="hashmap"> 
  select * 
  from users 
  <where> 
  <iterate var="i=0" increment> 
    ${columni} like #{valuei} 
  </iterate> 
  </where> 
</select>
```

Is there a way for me to accomplish something like that?

Comment: Can't figure out - what's your problem? Have you read mybatis documentation? Your scenario looks quite standard and simple.

Comment: In the documentation, http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html, you have to specify the columns by using if statements and the example with the foreach is only used to specify values in a IN condition. I imagine there has to be another way for me to accomplish what I want using foreach. Again what I want is to build a select statement where I can use column and value names dynamically.

Comment: The question answer and its usage can be found here:
[mybatis-generic-stmt-example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43356567/2762716)

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html):

> **String Substitution**
>
> By default, using the `#{}` syntax will cause MyBatis to generate PreparedStatement properties and set the values safely against the PreparedStatement parameters (e.g. `?`). While this is safer, faster and almost always preferred, sometimes you just want to directly inject a string unmodified into the SQL Statement. For example, for `ORDER BY`, you might use something like this:
>
> `ORDER BY ${columnName}`
>
> Here MyBatis won't modify or escape the string.

This allows you to e.g. pass column names as parameters to query etc.

Remember to **always** sanitize data that you are directly pasting to SQL.

---

If you need to generate multiple conditions for `WHERE` clause, use `<where>` tag with `<foreach>` inside. Note that `<foreach>` has advanced attributes that allow to specify separator, opening/ending string etc. Combined with `${}` notation I've mentioned before this allows construction of dynamic `WHERE` clause. For an example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560384/1995170).

Comment: but how do I add multiple where clauses? how can iterate the map to create the where clauses? I don't want to just put a String.

Comment: why won't you just use `<foreach>` inside `<where>` tag? see my updated answer.

Comment: glad I could help :) Please remember to accept an answer that was helpful to you.