# "super-dynamic" query with MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, db2-400

Is there way to create sql query on the fly with MyBatis? To concretize: I have a query, where part of it (but not parameter) needs to be created in the runtime:

```
         with dummy (id) as (
           values (#{rangeEnd}) union all
           select id - 1 from dummy where id - 1 >= #{rangeStart}   
         ).......
```

The second part can be used as parameter, but, when trying the query as it is I get an exception:

```
[SQL0584] NULL or parameter marker in VALUES not allowed.
```

With plain JDBC I use `MessageFormat`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
            MessageFormat.format(MY_QUERY, currentRange.getRangeEnd()))
```

, but I haven't found a way how to do it with MyBatis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy (answer from [Dynamic Select SQL statements with MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500425/dynamic-select-sql-statements-with-mybatis?rq=1)):

```
with dummy (id) as (
           values (${rangeEnd}) union all
           select id - 1 from dummy where id - 1 >= #{rangeStart}   
         ).......
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@SelectProvider` annotation:

```
public interface SqlMapper {
    static class PureSqlProvider {
        public String sql(String sql) {
           // Create your query here
           return sql; 
        }
    }

    @SelectProvider(type = PureSqlProvider.class, method = "sql")
    public List<Dummy> select(String sql);
}
```