# Oracle "LIMIT n,m" equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an oracle query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query)

I have this query

```
select * from pr_device_reading order by date_reading DESC
```

**Note** that this query is normalized, constructed by a method, and the table name will change according to the method's argument, so I can't specify the column names (and I do want all the columns in the result anyway).

What is the equivalent of

```
SELECT * 
 FROM pr_lecture_combustibles 
ORDER BY date_lecture DESC 
LIMIT 10,20;
```

using Oracle SQL?

I have tried

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM pr_lecture_combustibles 
         ORDER BY date_lecture DESC) 
 WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

and [other syntax](http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1214188-limit-clause-oracle-sql.html), but I get no result, "missing expression" messages and other errors.

Thanks

Comment: sorry, I didn't find that question doing a quick search

Comment: I believe you need to give an alias to the derived table. `FROM (....) AS A`.

Comment: In Oracle 12c use FETCH: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18972336/290182

Comment: It is a valid search. this is about alternate for limit clause which does much more than limiting rows.

Comment: This question's title is far more generic than the marked duplicate. I'd even say the title is _beautiful_. +1ed. @YanickRochon perhaps we can make this question a community wiki, and make the body more generic, thereby making this a canonical question?

Comment: An answer that works on Oracle 12c R1 and later: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26051830/1461424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can accept getting an additional column for the row number, you can apply the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and do something like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by date_lecture desc ) rn
          FROM pr_lecture_combustibles a)
 WHERE rn BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

But you'll get all the columns in the table **plus** the `RN` column