# SELECT into with DESC and ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle

My current query:

```
SELECT DACTIONMILLIS, DACTIONDATE INTO WF_DACTIONMILLIS, WF_DACTIONDATE 
FROM WORKFLOWHISTORY 
WHERE ddocname=? and LOWER(DACTION)=?
and lower(DWFSTEPNAME)=?
and lower(DUSER)=? 
and rownum = 1
ORDER BY DACTIONDATE desc;
```

But because the rownum is applied before the order by I'm getting invalid results. I found the following topic on stackoverflow: [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query) but that discusses a select, not a select into

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DACTIONMILLIS, DACTIONDATE INTO WF_DACTIONMILLIS, WF_DACTIONDATE 
FROM (
    SELECT DACTIONMILLIS, DACTIONDATE, WF_DACTIONDATE 
    FROM WORKFLOWHISTORY 
    WHERE ddocname=? and LOWER(DACTION)=?
    and lower(DWFSTEPNAME)=?
    and lower(DUSER)=? 
    ORDER BY DACTIONDATE desc
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The same approach applies as in the question you referenced:

```
SELECT DACTIONMILLIS, DACTIONDATE
INTO WF_DACTIONMILLIS, WF_DACTIONDATE 
from
( SELECT DACTIONMILLIS, DACTIONDATE
  FROM WORKFLOWHISTORY 
  WHERE ddocname=? and LOWER(DACTION)=?
  and lower(DWFSTEPNAME)=?
  and lower(DUSER)=? 
  ORDER BY DACTIONDATE desc
)
WHERE rownum = 1
```