# sql select from an ordered table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to ask some records from an ordered table.

```
select * from table_name order by something desc limit 4;
```

This is the error message (is the 'limit 4' line):

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 1
```

Comment: What is the Database type ? SQL Server, Oracle, My SQL ?

Comment: @ShashankKadne - given the error code is `ORA-xxxxx` where the `xxxxx` is 5 digits, I'm 99.99% certain that its Oracle.

Comment: Try this  `select * from table_name limit 4 order by something desc ;`

Comment: select * from table_name order by something desc limit '4';

Comment: I really wonder when they do "minus" for comments to downvote two previous comments...

Comment: Duplicate?: [SQL (ORACLE): ORDER BY and LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7480243/456814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ROWNUM` to limit the number of rows returned by a query

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

```
select * 
  (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY someval desc)
 WHERE ROWNUM < 5;
```