# Oracle Database Rownum Between

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

There are 25 records in this sql query
I want to get between 5 and 10. How can I do it ?
I use 11g

```
select
(
    select count(*) as sayfasayisi
    from konular t
    where t.kategori is not null
) as sayfasayisi,
t.id,
t.uye,
t.baslik,t.mesaj,t.kategori,t.tarih,
t.edittarih,t.aktif,t.indirimpuani,t.altkategori,t.link,
nvl(
    (select case when t.id = f.konuid and f.uye = 'test' then '1' else '0' end
     from takipkonu f where t.id = f.konuid and f.uye = 'test'), '0') as takip
from konular t
where t.kategori is not null
```

Comment: Oracle does not assign a permanent row number to records, so if you're looking for 5th to 10th record from your table, please know that it is not guaranteed that you will get the same records every time. For your specific question here, you need to see your specific requirement for retrieving only those records.

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a certain ordering and then retain only the 5th through 10th record.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480243/sql-oracle-order-by-and-limit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a row number based on some ordering logic contained in your current query, e.g. a certain column.  Then, retain only the 5th to 10th records:

```
select t.*
from
(
    select
    (
        select count(*) as sayfasayisi
        from konular t
        where t.kategori is not null
    ) as sayfasayisi,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn,
    t.id,
    t.uye,
    ...
) t
where t.rn between 5 and 10;
```