# How can I get just the first row in a result set AFTER ordering?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

This gives me just one row (the first one):

```
SELECT BLA
FROM BLA
WHERE BLA
AND ROWNUM < 2
```

However, I want the most recent date val; I can make that the first row this way:

```
SELECT BLA
FROM BLA
WHERE BLA
ORDER BY FINALDATE DESC
```

When I try to mix the two partial victories, though, it doesn't work - apparently the "Select the first row only" logic fires *before* the order by, and then the order by is subsequently ignored.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a group by (you will get the first row) ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This question is similar to [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering).

It talks about how to implement a MySQL limit on an oracle database which judging by your tags and post is what you are using.

The relevant section is:

```
select *
from  
  ( select * 
  from emp 
  order by sal desc ) 
  where ROWNUM <= 5;
```

Answer (score 54):

In 12c, here's the new way:

```
select bla
  from bla
 where bla
 order by finaldate desc
 fetch first 1 rows only;
```

How nice is that!

Answer (score 4):

You can nest your queries:

```
select * from (
    select bla
    from bla
    where bla
    order by finaldate desc
)
where rownum < 2
```