# Find the latest or earliest date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a foreign key called `team_ID`, a date column called `game_date`, and a single char column called `result`. I need to find when the next volleyball game happens. I have successfully narrowed the game dates down to all the volleyball games that have not happened yet because the result `IS NULL`. I have all the select in line, I just need to find the earliest date.

Here is what I've got:

```
SELECT game.game_date, team.team_name
FROM game
JOIN team
ON team.team_id = game.team_id
WHERE team.sport_id IN
    (SELECT sport.sport_id
    FROM sport
    WHERE UPPER(sport.sport_type_code) IN
        (SELECT UPPER(sport_type.sport_type_code)
        FROM sport_type
        WHERE UPPER(sport_type_name) like UPPER('%VOLLEYBALL%')
        )
    )
AND game.result IS NULL;
```

*I'm a time traveler so don't mind the old dates.*

When I run it, I get this:

```
GAME_DATE   TEAM_NAME
----------- ----------
11-NOV-1998 BEars
13-NOV-1998 BEars
13-NOV-1998 WildCats
14-NOV-1998 BEars
```

How do I set it up so I get *only* the `MIN(DATE)` and the `TEAM_NAME` playing on that date?

I've tried `AND game.game_date = MIN(game.game_date)` but it simply tells me that a group function in not allowed here. There has to be a way to retrieve the `MIN(game_date)` and use it as a condition to be met.

*I'm using Oracle 11g pl/sql.*

[image: Game ERD]

This should be the final working code.

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT g.game_date, t.team_name
      FROM game g
      JOIN team t
        ON t.team_id = g.team_id
      JOIN sport s
        ON t.sport_id = s.sport_id
      JOIN sport_type st
        ON UPPER(s.sport_type_code) IN UPPER(st.sport_type_code)
     WHERE UPPER(sport_type_name) like UPPER('%VOLLEYBALL%')
       AND g.result IS NULL
  ORDER BY g.game_date
    )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: That "final" code is not guaranteed to work as the `ROWNUM` psuedocolumn is generated before the `ORDER BY` clause is applied so you will get the first row in whatever order the database produces the rows and discard the rest and then will order the data. It appears to be working as the database is coincidentally producing the minimum row first but it is not guaranteed to work (and in most cases it won't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn is generated before any `ORDER BY` clause is applied to the query. If you just do `WHERE ROWNUM <= X` then you will get `X` rows in whatever order Oracle produces the data from the datafiles and not the `X` minimum rows. To guarantee getting the minimum row you need to use `ORDER BY` first and then filter on `ROWNUM` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT g.game_date, t.team_name
  FROM   game g
         JOIN team t
         ON t.team_id = g.team_id
         INNER JOIN sport s
         ON t.sport_id = s.sport_id
         INNER JOIN sport_type y
         ON UPPER( s.sport_type_code ) = UPPER( y.sport_type_code )
  WHERE  UPPER( y.sport_type_name) LIKE UPPER('%VOLLEYBALL%')
  AND    g.result IS NULL
  ORDER BY game_date ASC -- You need to do the ORDER BY in an inner query
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1; -- Then filter on ROWNUM in an outer query.
```

If you want to return multiple rows with the minimum date then:

```
SELECT game_date,
       team_name
FROM   (
  SELECT g.game_date,
         t.team_name,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY g.game_date ASC ) AS rnk
  FROM   game g
         JOIN team t
         ON t.team_id = g.team_id
         INNER JOIN sport s
         ON t.sport_id = s.sport_id
         INNER JOIN sport_type y
         ON UPPER( s.sport_type_code ) = UPPER( y.sport_type_code )
  WHERE  UPPER( y.sport_type_name) LIKE UPPER('%VOLLEYBALL%')
  AND    g.result IS NULL
)
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `rank()`? Also, I'm not finding any online resources that talk about the `over` function you used.

Comment: [`RANK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm) will rank the rows (similar to applying `ROWNUM`) but if multiple rows have equal value (based on the `ORDER BY` clause) then they will have the identical ranks (whereas `ROWNUM` will give each row a the next number in the sequence regardless of whether they have equal value or not). You can think or rank as if 2 runners have exactly the same time in a race then they will share the same podium place.

Comment: Ok, after some struggle I finally got a working code using what you described.

Comment: I do want to know why `rank` doesn't have any arguments in its parenthesis.

Comment: `RANK() OVER ()` is using the analytic syntax and not the aggregate syntax. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh. I get it. It's just bizarre to me to have that kind of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make it simple and order by date and SELECT TOP 1? I think this is the syntax in Oracle:

WHERE ROWNUM <= number;

Comment: That solves the problem at hand. I'll mark you as the answer once the site lets me but I'm probably going to make another question that specifically asks for a way to use a value retrieved from a `MIN` or `MAX` function as a condition to be met in a `WHERE COLUMN = MIN(COLUMN)`.

Comment: It is not quite as simple as adding `ROWNUM <= X` to the `WHERE` clause as the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn is generated before any `ORDER BY` clause is applied to the query. If you just do `WHERE ROWNUM <= X` then you will get `X` rows in whatever order Oracle produces the data from the datafiles and not the `X` minimum rows (and in the OP's example it just happens that the first row being produced is the minimum so this would appear to work when it is not guaranteed to do so).

Comment: In that case, you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978136/how-can-i-get-just-the-first-row-in-a-result-set-after-ordering

Answer (score 0):

```
select game.game_date,team.team_name from (
SELECT game.game_date, team.team_name, rank() over (partition by team.team_name order by game.game_date asc) T
FROM game
JOIN team
ON team.team_id = game.team_id
WHERE team.sport_id IN
    (SELECT sport.sport_id
    FROM sport
    WHERE UPPER(sport.sport_type_code) IN
        (SELECT UPPER(sport_type.sport_type_code)
        FROM sport_type
        WHERE UPPER(sport_type_name) like UPPER('%VOLLEYBALL%')
        )
    )
AND game.result IS NULL 
) query1 where query1.T=1;
```