# How to implement query limit or pagination in oracle

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

I am using just like below query:

```
SELECT url, title, metadesc FROM (
        SELECT url,title, metadesc, rownum rn FROM (
                SELECT url, title, metadesc FROM web
            )
            WHERE rownum <= 60
    )
    WHERE rn > 50
```

it works fine for single table but if do join in my main query 
i.e

```
SELECT name, id, url, title, metadesc
FROM web, emp
```

then it gives me error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering?rq=1

Comment: Starting from Oracle 12cR1, you can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT n ROWS`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26051830/1461424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either aliases:

```
SELECT e.name, e.id, w.url, w.title, w.metadesc
  FROM web w
  JOIN emp e ON w.xx = e.yy
```

Or full table names (more verbose):

```
SELECT emp .name, emp .id, web.url, web.title, web.metadesc
  FROM web
  JOIN emp ON web.xx = emp .yy
```

If a subquery returns two columns with the same name, you can't do a `SELECT *`:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM (
  2     SELECT d1.dummy, d2.dummy
  3       FROM dual d1, dual d2
  4  );

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

In that case use different column names in the subquery with aliases:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM (
  2     SELECT d1.dummy dummy_d1, d2.dummy dummy_d2
  3       FROM dual d1, dual d2
  4  );

D D
- -
X X
```

Comment: thanks a lot Vincent Malgrat its works 
but its take much time
 is there any other ways to implement pagination in oracle ?????

Comment: This would be an optimization question. I don't have enough data to answer. I suggest you create a new question with a description of your tables and their data and your query with its optimizer plan.