# how to get limited number of rows from combination of 2 queries

Tags: timesten

Iam facing some logical issues.Hope that someone can find me a solution to it

Iam having a query

```
select FirstName||'|'||LastName||to_char(salary) 
from (select FirstName,LastName,salary from subs_tbl where salary=24000) 
union all select FirstName||'|'||''||to_char(salary) 
from (select FirstName,LastName,salary from subs_tbl where salary=30000)
```

so my result will be

```
Satish|Kumar|24000

Vimal|Kumar|24000

Dinesh||30000
```

Let say am having 3 rows as my result but i need to add another condition to the whole query that i need only 2 rows out of the combination of these queries.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Try this  avoid union's that you have used

```
SELECT FirstName||'|'||LastName||to_char(salary) 
FROM subs_tbl 
WHERE salary=24000 or salary=30000) 
LIMIT 2
```

EDIT

```
SELECT fullname
FROM   (SELECT firstname
           || '|'
           || lastname
           || To_char(salary) AS 'FullName'
    FROM   (SELECT firstname,
                   lastname,
                   salary
            FROM   subs_tbl
            WHERE  salary = 24000)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT firstname
           || '|'
           || ''
           || To_char(salary) AS 'FullName'
    FROM   (SELECT firstname,
                   lastname,
                   salary
            FROM   subs_tbl
            WHERE  salary = 30000))
WHERE  rownum <= 5;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i cant use this coz my requirement is the resultant of both the queries results together that's why am using UNION  all function   as seen from the select part its different for both the queries which i have joined  select FirstName||'|'||LastName||to_char(salary)     and         select FirstName||'|'||''||to_char(salary)

Comment: This will also give you combined records only. Do you need random records from the result or top 2 ?

Comment: The thing is my select clause in both are different in first am concatinating FirstName|LastName|Salary   and in second query am concatinating FirstName||Salary, here the LastName should not be displayed   and the query should return in the firstway only if salary is 24000 and query should return second way only if salary is 30000

Comment: You need 1 from each group of 24k and 30k ? If so then add LIMIT 1 to each of your union

Comment: its not that i need one from each the limit value is dynamic it can be any value  as stated in the example                                  Satish|Kumar|24000

Vimal|Kumar|24000

Dinesh||30000                                                if the query returns these  then i need only the first two out of it.It need not be 2 like i said earlier it can be any number

Comment: is there someway in which this query can be made

Comment: Try this if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering

Answer (score 1):

```
select FirstName||'|'||LastName||to_char(salary) 
from (select FirstName,LastName from subs_tbl where salary=24000) 
union all select FirstName||'|'||''||to_char(salary) 
from (select FirstName,LastName from subs_tbl where salary=30000) limit 0,2
```

Comment: i tried out this suggestion by am getting an error                1001: Syntax error in SQL statement before or at: "0", character position: 185                                                              and also the number of rows to which i need to limit it is a dynamic value which will be passed to the procedure am using.                Note: Am using Oracle timesten to excecute it.

Comment: when the salary is 24000 then i need to display       Satish|Kumar|24000

Vimal|Kumar|24000                    firstname,lastname and salary    but when the salary is 30000 then i need to display              Dinesh||30000       firstname then a blank space in between the pipe and the salary so i need the combined result of both of these queries and thats why Iam using UNION ALL