# In SQL, how to select the top 2 rows for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as following:

```
NAME    SCORE
-----------------
willy       1
willy       2
willy       3
zoe         4
zoe         5
zoe         6
```

Here's the [sample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee665/1)

The aggregation function for `group by` only allow me to get the highest score for each `name`.
I would like to make a query to get the highest 2 score for each `name`, how should I do?

My expected output is

```
NAME    SCORE
-----------------
willy       2
willy       3
zoe         5
zoe         6
```

Comment: If using Oracle SQL, see [*How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/3357935)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   test s
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    test  f
            WHERE f.name = s.name AND 
                  f.score >= s.score
        ) <= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee665/18)

Comment: but that may cause performance issue. is there any other quicker way to implement this query?

Comment: This does indeed cause pretty heavy performance problems (the sub-select is quadratic).

Comment: This can be done linearly, see "MySQL Query to Get Top 2" here http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind having additional column then you can use the following code:

```
SELECT Name, Score, rank() over(partition by Name order by Score DESC) as rank
From Table
Having rank < 3;
```

**Rank function provides rank for each partition, in your case it is name**

Comment: I'm getting error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after "Name"

Answer (score 11):

In MySQL, you can use user-defined variables to get a row number in each group:

```
select name, score
from
(
  SELECT name,
    score,
    (@row:=if(@prev=name, @row +1, if(@prev:= name, 1, 1))) rn
  FROM test123 t
  CROSS JOIN (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) c
  order by name, score desc 
) src
where rn <= 2
order by name, score;
```

See [Demo](http://rextester.com/JSY60185)

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I'm still new in SQL. Hope that I can understand this one in the future :)

Comment: @waitingkuo Unfortunately MySQL does not have windowing functions which would allow you to easily assign a row number to each rows in a group.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks this is a very nice solution, it worked very fast even on 30k something rows, my earlier solution using joins was very slow

Comment: Is this safe?  MySQL states "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined." and doesn't that mean @prev:=name could be evaluated before your case statement and thus the case statement would artificially be true?  Or am I missing something?  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 5):

```
insert into test values('willy',1)
insert into test values('willy',2)
insert into test values('willy',3)
insert into test values('zoe',4)
insert into test values('zoe',5)
insert into test values('zoe',6)


;with temp_cte
as (
    select Name, Score,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY Name
          ORDER BY Score desc
       ) row_num
    from test
)
select * from temp_cte
where row_num < 3
```

Comment: Good first answer! Please test your code before posting (missing semicolons after  inserts). Explain it (using comments) as well as used concepts, e.g. `WITH` and [Common Table Expersion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthething like this:

```
SET @num :=0, @name :='';   
SELECT name, score,
    @num := IF( @name= name, @num +1, 1 ) AS row_number,
    @name := name AS dummy
FROM test
GROUP BY name, score
HAVING row_number <=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (   
    SELECT  VD.`cat_id` ,  
       @cat_count := IF( (@cat_id = VD.`cat_id`), @cat_count + 1, 1 ) AS 'DUMMY1', 
       @cat_id := VD.`cat_id` AS 'DUMMY2',
       @cat_count AS 'CAT_COUNT'   
     FROM videos VD   
     INNER JOIN categories CT ON CT.`cat_id` = VD.`cat_id`  
       ,(SELECT @cat_count :=1, @cat_id :=-1) AS CID  
     ORDER BY VD.`cat_id` ASC ) AS `CAT_DETAILS`
     WHERE `CAT_COUNT` < 4

------- STEP FOLLOW ----------  
1 . select * from ( 'FILTER_DATA_HERE' ) WHERE 'COLUMN_COUNT_CONDITION_HERE' 
2.  'FILTER_DATA_HERE'   
    1. pass 2 variable @cat_count=1 and  @cat_id = -1  
    2.  If (@cat_id "match" column_cat_id value)  
        Then  @cat_count = @cat_count + 1    
        ELSE @cat_count = 1      
    3. SET @cat_id = column_cat_id    

 3. 'COLUMN_COUNT_CONDITION_HERE'   
    1. count_column < count_number    

4. ' EXTRA THING '
   1. If you want to execute more than one statement inside " if stmt "
   2. IF(condition, stmt1 , stmt2 )
      1. stmt1 :- CONCAT(exp1, exp2, exp3) 
      2. stmt2 :- CONCAT(exp1, exp2, exp3) 
   3. Final "If" Stmt LIKE 
      1. IF ( condition , CONCAT(exp1, exp2, exp3) , CONCAT(exp1, exp2, exp3) )
```

Answer (score -1):

For this you can do this-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee665/4

but in order to get first 2 query, you should use a ID then run limit for ID like 0,2.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not what I expect

Comment: yea i was just giving method you can do it simply, if you have maintained ID for each row (primary key) it will work more and you will have more functions in hand. In the way you need its long code and also , it will be harder for you to use anything else over it in future.

Answer (score -2):

Use this query.

```
select * from fruits 
where type = 'orange'  
order by price limit 2
```

Solution Here:
https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/