# MYSQL: How to get Maximum and Second Maximum Date in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select Maximum Date and Second Max Date but can't get success.

This is table data.

```
ID Country  DATE 
1   Canada  2016-05-26
2   Canada  2016-05-25
3   Canada  2016-05-24

4   USA     2016-04-02
5   USA     2016-04-01
6   USA     2016-03-20
```

Expecting Output

```
Country  Max_Date    2nd_Date

Canada  2016-05-26  2016-05-25 
USA     2016-04-02  2016-04-01
```

What I have done so for:

Get Max Date using this query.

```
select Country, MAX(Date) from tbl GROUP BY (Country);
```

For Second Max date but failed to get result:

```
SELECT Country, MAX(date) FROM tbl WHERE Date NOT IN 

( select MAX(FROM) from tbl GROUP BY (Country)) GROUP BY (Country)
```

What should I try to get expected output. Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969614/in-sql-how-to-select-the-top-2-rows-for-each-group) post should point you in the right direction.  Possibly close as duplicate?

Comment: Select x.* from my_table x join my_table y on y.something = x.something and y.other_thing <= x.other_thing group by x.something, x.other_thing having count(*) <= 2;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could try this

```
SELECT s.Country, Max(s.Date) Max_Date, 
(SELECT t.Date 
 FROM tbl t 
 Where s.Country=t.Country 
 ORDER BY Date DESC 
 LIMIT 1,1) 2nd_Date
FROM tbl s
GROUP BY COUNTRY;
```

The LIMIT clause is zero based, so using parameters 1,1 skips the first (ie max) value & returns just one value (2nd max).

NOTE - if the max date is duplicated the query will return Max_Date & 2nd_Date as the same value - if that is not what you want, then you can add DISTINCT to the inner query.

Answer (score 2):

No need for nested queries to solve this:

```
SELECT t1.country, max(t1.date), max(t2.date)
FROM tbl t1
  JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.country = t2.country AND t2.date < t1.date
GROUP BY t1.country;
```

Comment: Perfect - very fast and clean.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a pain.  Here is one method:

```
select t.country, maxdate, max(t.date) as secondate
from tbl t left join
     (select country, max(date) as maxdate
      from tbl
      group by country
     ) c
     on t.country = c.country and  t.date < c.maxdate
group by t.country;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`Select Country, MAX(Date)  As Date  From tbl GROUP BY Country Order By Date Desc Limit 2;`

Comment: You have misread my question. I have just provided two countries example but I would be more than two countries. :)