# get first and second row from sql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
id term_id price
 2       1   100
 4       1   200
 6       1   500
 1       2   100
 3       3   100
 5       3   500
 7       3   700
```

I want only two row of all term id.

```
id term_id price
 4       1   200
 6       1   500
 1       2   100
 5       3   500
 7       3   700
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2`

Comment: What is the SQL? We need that, or a anonymized version of it to help you.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think I understand your question, hope my answer can help you.

Comment: Which two rows do you want? Are you willing to trust the random order of the rows in the database, or do you want to **Return the two rows with the lowest id for each given term_id**?

Comment: I need only two row of all same term id which has the highest id in the table. @John Rotenstein

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   test s
WHERE 
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) 
        FROM    test  f
        WHERE f.term_id = s.term_id and 
        f.price >= s.price
    ) <= 2;
```

example with your example table: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79a222/10

found here: [In SQL, how to select the top 2 rows for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969614/in-sql-how-to-select-the-top-2-rows-for-each-group)

Answer (score -1):

Three solutions

Using `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table;
```

Using `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM table
LIMIT 2;
```

And using `ROWNUM`

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2;
```