# SQL to fetch least 2 salaries from a table department wise

Tags: sql

How would be the SQL to fetch least 2 salaries from a table department wise ?

Sample Table:

```
empid  salary   Dept
---------------------
101     2000    aaa
102     1000    bbb
103     5000    bbb
104     8000    ccc
105     3000    aaa
106     4000    aaa
107     6000    ccc
108     7000    bbb
109     9000    ccc
```

Output should be like:

```
Dept  empid   salary
----------------------
aaa    101     2000
aaa    105     3000
bbb    102     1000
bbb    103     5000
ccc    104     6000
ccc    107     8000
```

Comment: What if there are ties?  Please clarify your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In SQL, how to select the top 2 rows for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969614/in-sql-how-to-select-the-top-2-rows-for-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t.dept
    ,t.empid
    ,t.salary
FROM
    #test t
WHERE
    t.empid IN (
        SELECT TOP 2
            empid
        FROM
            #test
        WHERE
            dept = t.dept
        ORDER BY
            salary
    )
ORDER BY
    dept,empid
```

As was pointed out, there may be other people in dept ccc with a salary of 8000 that will be missed.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [blog post](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) and supposing the table name is "samptab":

```
select dept, empid, salary
from samptab
where (
   select count(*) from samptab as s
   where s.dept = samptab.dept and s.salary <= samptab.salary
) <= 2 order by dept;
```

You can change the number "2" in the query row if you want more or less rows.