# MySQL Limit amount of rows per column value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have the following query

```
Select user_id, item_id
from some_table
```

And your result is this

```
10,20
10,21
10,22
10,23
10,24
11,30
11,31
11,32
11,33
11,34
```

What I really want is to only have 2 friend per each user, the following would be the desired output

```
10,20
10,21
11,30
11,31
```

How do you modify the query above to work this way without nested queries?

Comment: Try this sql fidddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dda15b/2/0  Following is the query:                                            SELECT user_id, item_id
FROM   some_table s
WHERE 
  (
   SELECT  COUNT(*) 
   FROM  some_table  f
   WHERE f.user_id = s.user_id AND 
      f.item_id <= s.item_id
  ) <= 2;

Comment: Is this doable without nested query?

Comment: check out this question very similar to yours, see if you find something : https://stackoverflow.com/q/15969614/15387341