# Display a range of rows from a table using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display rows 256 to 700 from a table 'customers'. Customers table can have rows in the millions. Customers table has primary key defined on 'cust_id'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering

Comment: Do you mean rows 256 to 700 when the rows are counted in some order, or do you mean `cust_id` should be between 256 and 700? That makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the fastest way is something like this:

```
select c.*
from (select rownum as seqnum, c.*
      from customers c
      where rownum <= 700
     ) c
where seqnum >= 256;
```

The only caveat is that the *order* of the rows is not defined in a `select` query.  To get things in the right order, you should use:

```
select c.*
from (select rownum as seqnum, c.*
      from (select c.*
            from customers c
            order by cust_id
           ) c
      where rownum <= 700
     ) c
where seqnum >= 256;
```