# ORA-00907 Missing right parenthesis Postgresql to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I am moving from Postgres to Oracle and I am getting the ORA-00907 error for the following statement:

```
UPDATE investigations SET 

team=(SELECT team FROM assigned WHERE parent_id=investigations.id LIMIT 1);
```

Please help with my Oracle syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're updating with a random row... is this intentional?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know oracle doesn't have `LIMIT` clause. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) topic

Comment: It does in 12c (just released).

Answer (score 2):

you can try using rownum

```
SELECT team FROM assigned WHERE parent_id=investigations.id and rownum =1
```

Comment: Good point - but as there was no order by in the original query, it should be pretty similar behaviour in this case