# Get some set of records in table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i want to select set of records in SQL Server table.

In SQL Server, I can do this:

```
select TOP 40,60 * 
from sometable
order by name
```

I want to get the 40th to the 60th rows.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering.

Comment: Actually - **no**; you cannot run this query in SQL Server - it doesn't know the `LIMIT` keyword, that's a MySQL-specific extension

Comment: I think the question is wrongly tagged. `LIMIT` is MySql syntax and the question is about Oracle and neither are tagged. Nothing to do with SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did that like this query

```
WITH temp AS
( SELECT *,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS 'RowNumber'
   FROM sometable 
) 
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 40 AND 60
```

Thank you for all comment.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT exists in Oracle but with different arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM sometbl Order by name LIMIT 40,100;  # Retrieve rows 41-100
```

Or you can proceed as;

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT st.*, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY name) rn FROM sometable st
) 
WHERE rn BETWEEN 40 AND 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Row_number` function and fetch the rows you need

```
WITH tmp AS  
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.name) AS 'rn', a.* FROM table a)
    SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE rn BETWEEN 40 AND 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT table.*, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY name) rank FROM table 
) 
WHERE rank BETWEEN 40 AND 60;
```