# How to select top five or 'N' rows in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, syntax-error

```
select distinct ani_digit, ani_business_line from cta_tq_matrix_exp limit 5
```

I want to select top five rows from my resultset. if I used above query, getting syntax error.

Comment: actually. i don't want to order my resultset. just I want 5 rows alone.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSukkoor - So you don't care which 5 rows you get?

Comment: yes. I am taking distinct of two column and any five rows are enough

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll need to use `DISTINCT` *before* you select the "top 5":

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT ani_digit, ani_business_line FROM cta_tq_matrix_exp) A
WHERE rownum <= 5
```

Comment: Thanks.. It s working

Answer (score 3):

```
  select distinct ani_digit, ani_business_line from cta_tq_matrix_exp where rownum<=5;
```

Comment: it is not working to my case.

Comment: this is a common mistake, where oracle 11 g, will pick N as per rownum randomly, and then do order. starting by oracle 12 c limit key word available. https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-rownum-and-limiting-results

Answer (score 2):

**LIMIT** clause is not available in Oracle.

Seeing your query, you seem to be interested only in a certain number of rows (not ordered based on certain column value) and so you can use **ROWNUM** clause to limit the number of rows being returned.

```
select distinct ani_digit, ani_business_line from cta_tq_matrix_exp WHERE rownum <= 5
```

If you want to order the resultset and then limit the number of rows, you can modify your query as per the details in the link provided by Colin, in the comments above.

Comment: yes. I did this query. but getting only one row in the resultset. if I used query like "select distinct ani_digit, ani_business_line from cta_tq_matrix_exp" getting three rows as result. i am feel some issue with distinct key.

Comment: Just.. use any one of you local table and take the distinct value of two columns and find the top five rows.

Comment: If you're getting 3 rows with `DISTINCT`, then `ROWNUM` cannot return just one row, or reduce the number of rows.

Comment: no. i am getting like that only. kindly try one example from your local database.

Comment: Check this, and let me know if it fits your case http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e16ba/1/0

Comment: your explaination is fine. But I don't know that why am i not getting this result from my table

Comment: **Equivalent of `LIMIT` clause _is_ available in Oracle** starting from 12cR1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26051830/1461424

Comment: Does this call still cause a full table scan? Or will the query stop after just pulling the first 5 rows? (We ask because we have been reading that row numbers are assigned *after* the query is run - and we are wondering if there is any way to decrease the processor load.)