# Oracle db pagination difficulties with query, error is : "command not properly ended"

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am doing the following query for pagination.
When I run

```
$s= oci_parse($conn,"select * from TBL_Name order by D_DATE desc");
$r = oci_execute($s);
```

then no error shown. When I write the following:

```
$s= oci_parse($conn,"select * from TBL_Name order by D_DATE desc limit $start,$limit");
$r = oci_execute($s);

error is:  oci_execute(): ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended .
```

That means problem is with `" limit $start,$limit "`, But I need this for pagination. LIMIT is not valid in Oracle perhaps. Now how can I write this query?

Comment: Oracle has ROWNUM to restrict rows fetched. But same time it cant be used like this.

Comment: when I write as $s= oci_parse($conn,"select * from TBL_Name order by D_DATE desc limit '$start','$limit'");  or give values as "limit 0,12" same problem is shown . @Alexander

Comment: Then what could be the prob ? @OracleUser

Comment: LIMIT is not supported in oracle. Hope this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) interests you!

Comment: My take, would be like.. you identify a unique column combination (probably PK )and use it for scrolling..  it would be faster.

Comment: Trying to write this query as you suggest , but facing difficulties in writing.

Comment: Can you update your question with it?

Comment: see the edited question, is it ok now ?

Comment: I updated the answer for you.. rownum is something genrated with your resultset.. so it can be always less than equla to.. so we first genrate the rownum for maximum limit and alias using a different name.. and use the alias referring from the outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROWNUM` is something genrated with your resultset as. *pseduocolumn*.. so it can be always less than equal to.. so we first generate the rownums for maximum limit and alias using a different name.. and use the alias referring from the outer query.

```
select * from 
( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from 
  (select * from TBL_Name order by D_DATE desc ) a 
  where ROWNUM <= $end )
where rnum  >= $start;
```

PHP code

```
// Parse a query containing a bind variable.
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, "    select * from  " +
                                          " ( select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from " +
                                          "   (select * from TBL_Name order by D_DATE desc ) a "+
                                          "    where ROWNUM <= :end) "+
                                          "   where rnum  >= :start) ");

// Bind the value into the parsed statement.
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":end", $end);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":start", $start);
```

Comment: this answer should be write, but same error is showing....I cant find out the cause.

Comment: for first iteration what values do you set,  i suspect they are passed null.. so query string is incomplete.

Comment: Ok got it.. the way use try to bind the variable is also wrong.

Comment: oh, I did a silly mistake. Now Its working well. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

`limit $start,$limit` is for MySQL only, it does not help with Oracle or other databases (although as noted by @Charles in the comments, LIMIT with OFFSET [is used elsewhere as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Result_limits)).

With Oracle, it is something like

```
select * from (
select foo.*, ROWNUM rnum
  from  
( select * from TBL_Name order by D_DATE desc  ) foo
 where ROWNUM <= $end) where rnum >= $start;
```

Comment: ROWNUM > is not possible, as it is a pseudocolumn!

Comment: FWIW, the `LIMIT` clause [is not just for MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Result_limits).

Comment: @Charles but `limit $start,$end` is, AFAIK.

Comment: @eis, [SQLite as well](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html), and that also made me research [if Postgres allows the comma (no)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT), wherein I have learned that SQL:2008 *finally* added syntax for result limiting... and of course, it's nothing like what any of the existing implementations do.  Glorious.

Comment: Ok, seems so. They don't seem to like supporting it, "programmers are strongly encouraged to use the form of the LIMIT clause that uses the "OFFSET" keyword and avoid using a LIMIT clause with a comma-separated offset." :)