# I want user to see only a particular row in sql table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want user to see only a particular row in sql table eg. if i have a table with 2 user if user 1 , writes

```
select * top1 from emp_id
```

the result must be 1st row.. but if 2nd user uses the same the answer should be 2nd row

Comment: Read up on  the LIMIT option in SQL statements

Comment: @shrmn : i dont think oracle offers `limit`, thats in `mysql`...

Comment: is it like your table has userid column to track if users can view rows corresponding to their ID's only?

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the Oracle tag. Sorry. In that case, maybe an equivalent of the LIMIT function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering

Comment: Is what you want row-level security? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E38689_01/pt853pbr0/eng/pt/tsec/task_DefiningRow-LevelSecurityandQuerySecurityRecords-c077b2.html

Comment: In Oracle 12c they introduced the `FETCH FIRST` clause which provides the same function like `LIMIT` on MySql.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view on emp_id table as below and provide select grant on the view (instead of providing grant on the table) to the user.

create or replace view v_emp_id
as
select * from emp_id
where user_name=user;

So the users can see their own data....