# DQL: enable (return_top 10) performance impact

Tags: dql, documentum

I had this query that originally caused massive timeouts:

```
select d.r_object_id 
from isc_fiche  d, dmr_con c 
where any c.parent_id = d.r_object_id 
group by d.r_object_id 
having count(*) > 2
```

yet when I add the `enable (return_top 10)` to the end then the performance issues seem a thing off the past. Apparently (according to colleagues) that statement could have a perfomance-improving effect.

Could someone clarify this for me?

Full query with 'way' better performance:

```
select d.r_object_id 
from isc_fiche  d, dmr_con c 
where any c.parent_id = d.r_object_id 
group by d.r_object_id 
having count(*) > 2 
enable(return_top 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enable (return_top 10)` modifies the executed SQL statement, it adds a limiting clause to it, like [`ROWNUM <= 10` in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/843804). It depends on the underlying RDBMS, so I guess it's not `ROWNUM <= 10` if you use EMC Documentum with Microsoft SQL Server.

You can run DQLs on the web interface of ECM Documentum (if I remember correctly it's called Webtop). There is a checkbox on the DQL run page which shows the generated SQL. You should check  there what's the difference between the two DQL query.

Comment: You remembered correctly! :) Tested both queries and the performance difference is quite remarkable, yet the results are the same! I've found a link on the net with some extra info & added it to your reply!