# How Can I set result set row count using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to set the number rows returned per query say 5. How can I set this in the sql query. 
Can any one please help me

Comment: Which DBMS ? MySQL ? MSSQL ? Oracle ?

Answer (score 1):

Highly dependent on what RDBMS you are using.

For Oracle

```
 SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE ROWNUM < 6
```

(since 12c there is [another option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972336/14955), too).

For Postgresql

```
 SELECT * FROM the_table LIMIT 5
```

Comment: And Also I want this for pagination

Answer (score 1):

According to the MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) you can do this by adding `LIMIT` statement to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
LIMIT offset, row_numbers
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
LIMIT row_numbers OFFSET offset
```

`offset` option is very useful in case of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggest zou can use:

```
select top X from table_name
```

where X is the numer of rows that you want

or you can use row_number

```
With cte AS 
( SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by table_column) as RowNumber  
FROM table_name) 
select * 
from cte
Where RowNumber <= 5
```

or even:

```
With cte AS 
( SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by table_column) as RowNumber  
FROM table_name) 
select * 
from cte
Where RowNumber between 5 and 10
```

Comment: In tha case when we are talking about MSSQL