# Java return SQL statement

Tags: java, sql

I am doing code review, and in many cases I found result is not closed if SQL statement returns the records. The business rule for SQL statement is consider only the first record.

Below is the code where I am confused, Why is it returning the value without closing resultset and statement? Is this correct way?

```
if (rs.next()){
        return new Long(rs.getLong(1));
}
```

Below is sample code:

```
private static Long <MethodName>
     (
         oracle.sql.NUMBER[] o_errorCode,
         oracle.sql.CHAR[] o_errorText,
         Long portA,
         Long portZ) throws SQLException
     {
         String errorMessage = "";
         Long[] NROLE = new Long[1];
         Long[] pTask = new Long[1];
         Long dimObject = null;
         Long objectIDA = null;
         Long objectIDZ = null;
         Long relation = null;
         Connection tmpConn = null;
         Statement stmt = null;
         ResultSet rs = null;
         String SQL = null;
         try
         {
             // Retrieve the Epipe circuits that are on the specified ports
             stmt = DbUtil.getConn().createStatement();
             String query = "Select * from Circuit where ... Order by Id";
                 rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
              if (rs.next()){
                     return new Long(rs.getLong(1));
                }
                 rs.close();
                 stmt.close();
             return null;
         }
         catch (SQLException ex)
         {
             o_errorCode[0] = new oracle.sql.NUMBER(1);
             o_errorText[0] = new oracle.sql.CHAR("SQLException - " + ex.getMessage(),
             oracle.sql.CharacterSet.make(oracle.sql.CharacterSet.DEFAULT_CHARSET));
             return(null);
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             o_errorCode[0] = new oracle.sql.NUMBER(1);
             o_errorText[0] = new oracle.sql.CHAR("Exception - " + e.getMessage(), oracle.sql.CharacterSet.make(
             oracle.sql.CharacterSet.
             DEFAULT_CHARSET));
             return(null);
         }
}
```

Comment: How manage resource closing in `finally` block?

Answer (score 2):

Not correct, and since Java 7 easily resolved when using try-with-resources:

```
try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
    if ...
        return ...
}
```

---

That `if rs.next()` might do with a better SQL: a kind of [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) or a MIN(Id) of a kind.

It is not good style too:

1. Use a consistent style: `SELECT FROM WHERE ORDER BY` or `select from where by`.
2. Do not use database specific classes; JDBC took much effort to not need it.
3. I almost suspect that here a **PreparedStatement** could have been used. Aside from preventing SQL injection it escapes parameters nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `finally`.

```
    try {
            // Retrieve the Epipe circuits that are on the specified ports
            stmt = DbUtil.getConn().createStatement();
            String query = "Select * from Circuit where ... Order by Id";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if (rs.next()) {
                return new Long(rs.getLong(1));
            }

            return null;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct place to close database resources like result set, statement or connection is the **finally** block of a try-catch statement. Because, JVM visits this block in any condition.

The following usage is safe:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmt = null;
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = SomeDBUtility.getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("<Your SQL string>");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // handle the exception
} finally {
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```