# Query to get the "MAX COUNT"

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys I have the following query:

```
select count(*) AS num_items
       from desc_look
       group by dept
```

This query returns the number of items in each department. However I can't get ONLY the department with the higher number of items.

I've been trying to use this to retrieve the name and id of the department with most items

```
select dept, desc_up
from desc_look
where (select count(*) AS num_items
       from desc_look
       group by dept)
```

However I keep getting an error ORA-00936 and I don't know why.
I know I can't user MAX(COUNT(*)) but is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: Does the `desc_up` column always contain the department name that matches `dept_id` of the same row, i.e. both the department name and id are store in the `desc_look` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from
(
    select count(*) AS num_items
    from desc_look
    group by dept
    order by count(*) desc
) tmp
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Also have a look on [howto limit the records in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering).

Comment: This answer does not return the department name and id which the OP requested.

Answer (score 2):

This version is basically the same as juergen's, but using an analytic function instead of an aggregate (`GROUP BY`) for counting:

```
SELECT t.dept, t.desc_up FROM
  (SELECT dept, desc_up,
   COUNT(*) over (partition BY dept) dept_count
   FROM desc_look
   ORDER BY dept_count DESC
  ) t
WHERE rownum = 1
```

If you're on Oracle 12, the inline view is not needed because you can use the row-limiting clause (`FETCH FIRST ...`):

```
SELECT dept, desc_up,
  COUNT(*) over (partition BY dept) dept_count
FROM desc_look
ORDER BY dept_count DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you

```
select count(*) AS num_items
       from desc_look
       group by dept
       order by count(*) desc
       limit 1
```

Comment: I don't think one can use `LIMIT` in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT dept, num_items FROM (
    SELECT dept, COUNT(*) AS num_items
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
      FROM desc_look
     GROUP BY dept
) WHERE rn = 1;
```