# How to convert MS SQL Stored Procedure to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am stuck with  this query. I try to convert but, i new at Oracle 11 g.

This is the ms sql stored procedure to convert with Oracle 11 g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomers_Pager]
       @SearchTerm VARCHAR(100) = ''
      ,@PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY [CustomerID] ASC
      )AS RowNumber
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[CompanyName]
      ,[ContactName]
      ,[City]
      INTO #Results
      FROM [Customers]
      WHERE [ContactName] LIKE @SearchTerm + '%' OR @SearchTerm = ''
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

I find this ms sql stored procedure to [this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Search-GridView-with-Paging-on-TextBox-KeyPress-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx)

This is my fail oracle stored procedure. I'm stuck with INTO syntax.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE GetCustomers_Pager
( SearchTerm IN VARCHAR2
, PageIndex IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1
, PageSize IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10
, RecordCount OUT NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN  
  SELECT  
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CustomerID ASC )AS RowNumber,
          ,CustomerID
          ,CompanyName
          ,ContactName
          ,City
  INTO Results
  FROM Customers
  WHERE ( Customers LIKE SearchTerm + '%' OR ContactName LIKE SearchTerm + '%') OR SearchTerm = '';
  SELECT RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM Results;
  SELECT * FROM Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(PageIndex -1) * PageSize + 1 AND(((PageIndex -1) * PageSize + 1) + PageSize) - 1;
  DROP TABLE Results;

END GetCustomers_Pager;
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What oracle version do you use? [perhaps this may help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: First thing to do is to remove the `[..]` "quotes". Those are invalid for an SQL identifier.

Comment: I don't think the original SQLServer procedure makes any sense. It seems to be doing this: 1) Inserts a bunch of data from the `Customers` table that matches a contact name, into a temporary table `#Results`. 2) Fetches the row count of `#Results` into the `OUT` parameter `RecordCount`. 3) Executes a redundant query that mimicks pagination, against the `Results` table. The paginated result set is not used anywhere. 4) `DROP`s table `#Results`. Unless there is some hidden SQLServer magic going on, I think the same thing could be accomplished with a single `COUNT` against the `Customers` table.

Comment: First thing as per your pasted procedure you have 2 commas at SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CustomerID ASC )AS RowNumber,
    , and then into clause must have the same number of argument as in select statement

Comment: @MickMnemonic: There is indeed some "magic" going on, the procedure will (implicitely) return the result of the last select statement - that's why Oracle 12c introduced the "implicit result sets as well", but this is not available in 11g. I think the only option is to use a pipelined function that returns a result set and then select from that function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, wow that's really unintuitive (but nice to know)! Is the way it's used here an idiomatic usage example? Also, it feels awfully clumsy to implement pagination through a temp table and a stored procedure. Using a simple `SELECT` with an analytic windowing function like `row_number()` and an inline view (as presented by Tom Kyte [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html)) is how I think it's best done in Oracle. I'd assume you can use almost the same syntax in the latest versions of SQLServer, as well.

Comment: @MickMnemonic: I'm not really a SQL Server guy, but I do see that all the time. It's one of the biggest obstacles and areas of confusion when people migrate from SQL Server to Oracle as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only simple type variable in the `SELECT INTO` clause, for selecting into array use `SELECT BULK COLLECT INTO`. However you have to declare the variable you are selecting into and its type must match.

If you want to select the count only, use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RecordCount
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CustomerID ASC )AS RowNumber,
             CustomerID,
             CompanyName,
             ContactName,
             City
     FROM Customers
     WHERE ( Customers LIKE SearchTerm + '%' OR ContactName LIKE SearchTerm + '%') OR SearchTerm = '') s
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN (PageIndex-1)*PageSize + 1 AND PageIndex*PageSize;
```

If you want to return the records, you have to define the array type, add the output parameter `Records` and use `SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO Records` and then `RecordCount := Records.COUNT;`.

But the preferred way to return data is a `REF CURSOR` output parameter, see http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle procedure code with cursor as output parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetCustomers_Pager (
  SearchTerm IN VARCHAR2, PageIndex IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1, PageSize IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10, 
  RecordCount OUT NUMBER, Records out sys_refcursor ) AS

begin
  -- count all matching rows
  select count(1) into RecordCount from Customers
    where ContactName like SearchTerm||'%';

  -- get all matching rows into cursor "Records"
  -- and filter them including PageIndex and PageSize parameters
  open Records for 
  select rn, customerid, companyName, contactName, City 
    from (
      select row_number() over (order by customerID) rn,
          customerid, companyName, contactName, City
        from customers where ContactName like SearchTerm||'%' )
    where rn between (PageIndex-1) * PageSize
      and (((PageIndex-1) * PageSize + 1) + PageSize) - 1;
end GetCustomers_Pager;
```

Example C# code calling this procedure and filling DataGridView:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "getcustomers_pager";
cmd.Connection = CONNECTION.oconn;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("SearchTerm", OracleType.VarChar, 3)).Value = "Mar";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PageIndex", OracleType.Number)).Value = 1;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PageSize", OracleType.Number)).Value = 5;
OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter("RecordCount", OracleType.Number);
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
p = new OracleParameter("Records", OracleType.Cursor);
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I create the oracle stored procedure but i'm using Ole DB dll. how can i use Oracle dll ? Any advice ?  Tkanks...

Comment: According to my knowledge you should just replace `OracleCommand` with `OracleDBCommand`, `OracleType` with `OracleDBType` etc.,
look what Intellisense suggest. Not sure of that, but this should work, just google for examples.

Comment: OracleType.Cursor does not support with Ole Db. Probably i can use oracle data access dll. Thanks for your help.