# Returning MAX function on query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, max

I need to find the Stock Item with the greatest profit margin, however am unsure on how to do so as this was calculated within the query and not taken from a table.
My script is as follows (Using Oracle 11g), and currently returns several stock items when I need only one. Please help

```
SELECT (UPPER(Orderline.StockID) || ' ' || INITCAP(StockDesc)) AS "Item",
CategoryDesc AS "Category",
LocationCity AS "Warehouse",
Quantity AS "Number Sold",
TO_CHAR(Quantity * UnitPrice) AS "Total Income",
TO_CHAR(Quantity * UnitCost) AS "Total Cost",
TO_CHAR((Quantity * UnitPrice) - (Quantity * UnitCost)) AS "Profit"
FROM Orderline INNER JOIN 
(Stock INNER JOIN 
("CATEGORY" INNER JOIN Warehouse
ON "CATEGORY".Warehouse = Warehouse.WarehouseID)
ON Stock.ItemCategory = "CATEGORY".CategoryID)
ON Orderline.StockID = Stock.StockNo
ORDER BY ((Quantity * UnitPrice) - (Quantity * UnitCost)) DESC;
```

Comment: you need to retrieve max 'Profit' field?

Comment: Wrap your query in `select * from (... your query here ...) x where rownum = 1` (per Bacon Bit's suggestion)

Comment: @JessRap  
highest profit per.....? item? category? warehouse?

Comment: @Andomar That does not work without a subquery, inline view, or WITH clause.  WHERE is before ORDER BY.

Comment: @Matt highest profit per item

Comment: @Andormar I tried this, but it returned the first item listed, not that with the greatest profit ...

Comment: @miraclefoxx yes exaclty, highest profit with regards to the item, just unsure on how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
select * from (SELECT (UPPER(Orderline.StockID) || ' ' || INITCAP(StockDesc)) AS "Item",
        CategoryDesc AS "Category",
        LocationCity AS "Warehouse",
        Quantity AS "Number Sold",
        TO_CHAR(Quantity * UnitPrice) AS "Total Income",
        TO_CHAR(Quantity * UnitCost) AS "Total Cost",
        TO_CHAR((Quantity * UnitPrice) - (Quantity * UnitCost)) AS "Profit"
        FROM Orderline INNER JOIN 
        (Stock INNER JOIN 
        ("CATEGORY" INNER JOIN Warehouse
        ON "CATEGORY".Warehouse = Warehouse.WarehouseID)
        ON Stock.ItemCategory = "CATEGORY".CategoryID)
        ON Orderline.StockID = Stock.StockNo
        ORDER BY Profit DESC)
        where rownum = 1;
```

I've seen in the comments that you've tried `rownum=1` on the inner select... This would select the only `Item` and sort it with `order by`. There's not many ways to sort a set of one element. But if you'll have sorted set of all elements, you can just pick the first. That's what happens here.

---

See more info about this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering?rq=1).