# Getting the Highest value from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, max, sql-limit

I am trying to display just the first row, in MYSQL the example was:

```
ORDER BY foo DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I believe oracle does not use the `LIMIT` clause.  I have tried the `ROWNUM = 1`, but it does not seem to work.  Is this the proper way of displaying the first line?

```
select customer_name, 
       MAX(balance) as "Highest Depositor Value"
  from depositor
 inner join account
    on depositor.account_number = account.account_number
 group by customer_name, balance
 order by balance
 where rownum = 1;


ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I got the answer! Thanks

```
select customer_name,max(balance) as "Highest Depositor Value"
 from depositor
 inner join account
    on depositor.account_number = account.account_number
 group by customer_name, balance order by balance desc
 fetch first 1 rows only;


CUSTOMER_NAME   Highest Depositor Value
 --------------- -----------------------
 Lindsay                          100000
```

Answer (score 1):

remove this part:

`order by balance where rownum = 1`

and what you have should work ..

MAX will give you the largest ... you don't need to tell it how many rows, MAX will only give the 1 largest value.

[edit]
if you just want the 1 largest value, you need to remove the group/order by .. and also remove "customer name" from select:

```
  select MAX(balance) as "Highest Depositor Value"
  from depositor
  inner join account on depositor.account_number = account.account_number;
```

[/edit]

Comment: I tried that and I end up with 11 rows selected. That is why I wanted to order them and display the first row.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry .. 11 rows, 1 row per group .. you grouped on customer name, balance .. perhaps you don't want to group ? you just the 1 max value? remove both GROUP by and ORDER by ..

Comment: I will give a little background.  the customer_name come from the depositor table.  each customer_name can have several accounts.  I used group to group them together and get a total value of there accounts. I can get a nice result like that. The problem is I just wanted the max value of the grouped customers.  Maybe grouping was not the way to go for adding the values up, but it was the way I proceeded I can see the top value but i am not able display only that value.

Comment: Post this information in the original question .. include sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer explained well here.

[How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering/26051830#26051830)

> ```
>   select customer_name,max(balance) as "Highest Depositor Value"
> 2  from depositor
> 3  inner join account on depositor.account_number = account.account_number
> 4  group by customer_name, balance order by balance desc
> 5  fetch first 1 rows only;
> CUSTOMER_NAME   Highest Depositor Value
>  --------------- -----------------------
>  Lindsay                          100000
> ```