# SQL to split the total number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm reading a table from a Java app and now I wanted to split this task across two different apps each processing its own rows.

I tried to use this

```
Select * from emp where rownum between 0 and (Select count(*) from emp)/2;
```

I need your suggestion on the best way to read the next half of the table.

I tried

```
Select * from emp where rownum between ((Select count(*) from emp)/2)+1 and (Select count(*) from emp);
```

but it didn't give me results ( gave me a empty set of records )

Comment: is this oracle or mysql ? mysql does not have rownum.. also define `didnt give me results`

Comment: its Oracle, and it gave me a empty set of records.

Comment: which version you are using.?

Comment: @DharaniDharan The latest one :)

Comment: You are using oracle 12 c.. this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering/26051830#26051830] may help you

Answer (score 0):

`rownum` is assigned to the rows *after* the result was fetched, so you can't use it as you did. Instead you can do something like:

```
   select *
   from (select rownum r, e.* from emp e)
   where r between ((Select count(*) from emp)/2)+1 and (Select count(*) from emp);
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the same row is not fetched by both apps. The rows must be ordered.

Comment: That's why I wrote `something like`. OP will decide by himself how exactly he will order the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can also interleave the rows

Assuming sequential id:

App 1: `Select * from emp where mod(emp_id, 2) = 0;`

App 2: `Select * from emp where mod(emp_id, 2) = 1;`

or

App 1:

```
WITH emp_ordered AS (Select * from emp order by emp_id)
Select * FROM (Select emp.*, rownum rn from emp_ordered) where mod(rn, 2) = 0;
```

App 2:

```
WITH emp_ordered AS (Select * from emp order by emp_id)
Select * FROM (Select emp.*, rownum rn from emp_ordered) where mod(rn, 2) = 1;
```