# First record which meets GROUP BY and HAVING clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL Server query which takes data from Oracle 8i server using linked server connection. My question here is completely on Oracle SQL.

There is a StyleSizes table.  One style can have one or more sizes associated with it. I need to find any one Style_CD which has more than one Size_CD.  This can be achieved by GROUP BY and HAVING. But I need only one such style. The volume of the table is so big that I cannot wait till the query execution is complete – so I need only one style.

How to get only one record quickly after applying GROUP BY and HAVING clauses in Oracle?

```
SELECT STYLE_CD
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedORAServer,  
   'SELECT STYLE_CD
   FROM DA.StyleSize M  
   GROUP BY STYLE_CD
   HAVING COUNT(SIZE_CD) > 1
    ')
```

**FURTHER READING**

1. [Ask Tom - On ROWNUM and Limiting Results](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)
2. [Limit - Comparison of different SQL implementations](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit)
3. [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering/26051830#26051830)
4. [Row Limiting Clause for Top-N Queries in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1)
5. [SQL Server - Pagination with OFFSET / FETCH : A better way](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch)

Comment: Can you go with Select top 1?

Comment: @Veljko89 Do you mean TOP 1 in SQL Server or Oracle? It's no use to do it in SQL Server becuase it is an OPENQUERY.

Comment: What are you trying to get?  One style that has multiple sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one style that has more than one size, quickly, then you can use `exists`:

```
select m.*
from da.stylesize m
where exists (select 1 from da.stylesize m2 where m2.style_cd = m.style_cd and m2.size_cd <> m.size_cd) and
      rownum = 1;
```

Then, you want to be sure you have an index on `da.stylesize(style_cd, size_cd)`.

With this query, you don't even need to do the aggregation, which should be a big savings.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However in SQL Server, I can apply TOP 1 in a query with GROUP BY (and it uses different and efficient query plan). Why is Oracle not allowing TOP 1 on GROUP BY? [Your suggestion works fast enough - but it is difficult to read compared to GROUP BY aproach when more tables are involved].

Comment: @Lijo . . . Oracle doesn't support `TOP` in any query.

Comment: Agreed - I already know that. I was referring to the approach. I consider `rownum = 1` in `where` and `Top 1` as logically same. SQL Server works fast  with TOP 1 and GROUP BY - but Oracle is not working fast with `GROUP BY` and `rownum`. Is it a shortcoming of Oracle?

Comment: @Lijo . . . They are not quite equivalent.  `TOP` is evaluated *after* `ORDER BY`.  `WHERE` is evaluated before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Lijo . . . Oracle 12c supports the `fetch` clause which is the ANSI equivalent of `TOP` (actually better because it also allows an offset).

Answer (score 2):

You should use ROWNUM which is similar to MySQL limit and SQL-SERVER top :

```
SELECT STYLE_CD
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedORAServer,  
   'SELECT STYLE_CD FROM(SELECT STYLE_CD
                         FROM DA.StyleSize M  
                         GROUP BY STYLE_CD
                         HAVING COUNT(SIZE_CD) > 1)
    WHERE rownum = 1
    ')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT SIZE_CD, COUNT(STYLE_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY STYLE_CD) CNT FROM STYLESIZE) WHERE CNT > 1
```

Comment: Oracle 8i didn't have analytic functions I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STYLE_CD
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedORAServer,  
   'select VAL from (
select VAL,COUNT(*) from SANDEEP24FEB2016_2 group by VAL having COUNT(*)>1 
) where rownum=1
    ') ;
```