# get error in select the nth column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I tried to select the `secondhighestsalary` from the employee table, this was my go, but it returned

> the SQL statement is not properly ended

```
select salary as secondhighestsalary from employee 
order by salary desc
offset 1 rows
fetch next 1 rows only;
```

What is the problem right there? Oracle SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `select salary as secondhighestsalary 
  from employee 
  WHERE rownum BETWEEN 1 and 1;
 order by salary desc
`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this construction is supported starting Oracle 12 c
[Oracle 11g OFFSET FETCH gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836391/oracle-11g-offset-fetch-gives-error)