# How to return 1 row for each distinct value in a given column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

I have data that looks like

```
NBR  ID  DT
1    1   01-DEC-01 
1    2   01-JAN-01
2    3   01-JAN-01
2    4   O2-JAN-01
```

I want to get just one row for each `NBR`, with the earliest date.
So I want the result to be

```
NBR  ID  DT
1    2   01-JAN-01
2    3   01-JAN-01
```

However, I can't use `LIMIT` because I'm using Oracle. I tried the following but its not giving the result I expect

```
select DISTINCT NBR, ID, DT
from tablename
group by NBR, ID, DT
order by DT
```

EDIT: This is NOT a duplicate of that link because I am grouping by NBR. I want one row for each distinct NBR.

Comment: It is dupliate! :)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26051830/6049590
Should be exactly what he searches

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of that link because I am grouping by NBR. I want one row for each distinct NBR.

Answer (score 4):

The solution has nothing to do with `limit` or `order by`, Oracle or not. you want to use the `row_number` analytic function to solve this easily:

```
select nbr, id, dt
  from (select nbr, id, dt,
               row_number() over (partition by nbr order by dt) as rn
          from tbl)
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [the `FIRST` analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641):

```
select NBR,
  min(ID) keep (dense_rank first order by DT) as ID,
  min(DT) keep (dense_rank first order by DT) as DT
from tablename
group by NBR
order by DT;

       NBR         ID DT                
---------- ---------- -------------------
         2          3 2001-01-01 00:00:00
         1          2 2001-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) with an aggregate function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( NBR, ID, DT ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2001-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2001-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, DATE '2001-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4, DATE '2001-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT NBR,
       MAX( ID ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DT ) AS ID,
       MIN( DT ) AS DT
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY NBR;
```

**Output**:

```
       NBR         ID DT                
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          2 2001-01-01 00:00:00 
         2          3 2001-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    tablename t
    INNER JOIN 
    (
       SELECT
          NBR
          ,MIN(DT) AS DT
       FROM
          tablename
       GROUP BY
          NBR
    ) g
    ON t.NBR = g.NBR
    AND t.DT = g.DT
```

I love the window funtions and ctes as much as everyone else on this site. Here is an old school way not using those for fun.  note if there is duplicate earliest `DT` for NBR you will get multiple rows for that `NBR`

In case of having duplicate earliest `DT` per `NBR` you can do yet another level of aggregation so this is getting even crazier.  On the next level you get the `min(ID)` and then relate it back to the table.  If window functions are an option they really are a better choice.........

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
    tablename t1
    INNER JOIN 
       (
        SELECT t.NBR, MIN(t.ID) AS ID
        FROM
             tablename t2
             INNER JOIN 
             (
                SELECT
                  NBR
                  ,MIN(DT) AS DT
                FROM
                  tablename t3
                GROUP BY
                  NBR
             ) g
             ON t.NBR = g.NBR
             AND t.DT = g.DT
        GROUP BY
          t.NBR
       ) m
    ON t1.NBR = m.NBR
    AND t1.ID = m.ID
```

Comment: But I only want it to return one row if there is a duplicate earlier DT for NBR

Comment: the row_number window function is the best for that is that not an option. how would you choose which record if they are duplicate the lowest id?

Comment: @user6347191 look at the bottom of my answer if you really don't want to do this via window functions and you will see away to get only 1 record arbitrarily when duplicate earliest DT exists per NBR

Comment: `DT = MIN(DT)` is invalid SQL. Also: Oracle was actually the first DBMS to support window functions. It has had it since version 8

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the tip I don't write oracle syntax basically ever, I changed to min(id) as id and min(dt) as dt.  I just writing the crazy answer because the user seems to have an aversion to window functions but I am glad to know about oracle being first to support!

Comment: `DT = MIN(DT)` being invalid has nothing to do with Oracle. It's simply not allowed in (standard) SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I take it this is a pet peeve of yours.  I get that sql-server which obviously I work on primarily doesn't always adhere to ANSI standards and column aliasing would be one of those examples, but when I write for sql-server I will likely continue because having all column names on the left makes my code easier to read for me.  I will make a point to not use that syntax for any answer which is not specifically for sql-server on here.