# How to sort version numbers (like 5.3.60.8)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Strings like:

```
5.3.60.8 
6.0.5.94
3.3.4.1
```

How to sort these values in sorting order in Oracle SQL?

I want the order to be like this:

```
6.0.5.94
5.3.60.8
3.3.4.1
```

Comment: What is the "sorting order"? First by the first number, then by the second, etc.?

Comment: Do you always have exactly four parts?

Comment: Yes...Gordon...Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show here the answer from [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3580237700346153677), which can be used with different version size :

```
WITH inputs 
     AS (SELECT 1 as id, '6.0.5.94' as col FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2,'5.3.30.8' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3,'5.3.4.8' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4,'3' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5,'3.3.40' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6,'3.3.4.1.5' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 7,'3.3.4.1' FROM DUAL)
    SELECT col, MAX (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (v, '.')) p
      FROM (SELECT t.col, TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (x.COLUMN_VALUE, 1, 5)) r, SUBSTR (x.COLUMN_VALUE, 6) v, id rid
              FROM inputs t,
                   TABLE (
                      CAST (
                         MULTISET (
                                SELECT    TO_CHAR (LEVEL, 'fm00000')
                                       || TO_CHAR (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR ('.' || col || '.', INSTR ('.' || col || '.', '.', 1, ROWNUM) + 1, INSTR ('.' || col || '.', '.', 1, ROWNUM + 1) - INSTR ('.' || col || '.', '.', 1, ROWNUM) - 1)), 'fm0000000000')
                                  FROM DUAL
                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (col) - LENGTH (REPLACE (col, '.', '')) + 1) AS SYS.odciVarchar2List)) x)
START WITH r = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rid = rid AND PRIOR r + 1 = r
  GROUP BY col
  ORDER BY p
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select '6.0.5.94' from dual union all
       select '5.3.60.8' from dual union all
       select '3.3.4.1'  from dual
     )
select str from inputs
order by to_number(regexp_substr(str, '\d+', 1, 1)), 
         to_number(regexp_substr(str, '\d+', 1, 2)),
         to_number(regexp_substr(str, '\d+', 1, 3)),
         to_number(regexp_substr(str, '\d+', 1, 4))
;

STR
--------
3.3.4.1
5.3.60.8
6.0.5.94
```

Comment: I suppose that you should use to_number in order by, if you don't want 30 to be before 4.

Comment: Darn - I meant to do that and I forgot! I will edit to fix that, it absolutely is needed. Thanks!

Comment: But here I have not only 3 values....I have more than 200 strings...in this case how to get it from table name called versions?

Comment: @KrishnaNagidi Use your table name instead of 'inputs' and your column name instead of 'str'

Comment: @KrishnaNagidi ... what Mottor said, and in addition, you don't need the first six rows; your query will be `select ... ` where the first word after `select` will not be `str` but the name of the column in your table that holds the values, and `inputs` is replaced by your table name (perhaps `versions` if that is what you meant). DON'T FORGET to replace `str` with your actual column name in the call to regexp_substr() in the ORDER BY clause too - four substitutions there and five total for `str`.

Comment: I did the changes..now its working perfectly..Thank you very much for your kind support

Comment: Glad it worked! If any of the answers posted here helped solve your problem, you should mark the question as "answered" so volunteers on the forum can concentrate on unanswered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could pad numbers with zeroes on the left in the `order by`  clause:

```
select   version
from     versions
order by regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(version, '(\d+)', lpad('\1', 11, '0')),
            '\d+(\d{10})',
            '\1'
         ) desc
```

This works for more number parts as well, up to about 200 of them.

If you expect to have numbers with more than 10 digits, increase the number passed as second argument to the `lpad` function, and also the braced number in the second regular expression. The first should be one more (because `\1` is two characters but could represent only one digit).

#### Highest version

To get the highest version only, you can add the row number to the query above with the special Oracle `rownum` keyword. Then wrap all that in an another `select` with a condition on that row number:

```
 select version
 from (
      select   version, rownum as row_num
      from     versions
      order by regexp_replace(
                  regexp_replace(version, '(\d+)', lpad('\1', 11, '0')),
                  '\d+(\d{10})',
                  '\1'
               ) desc)
where row_num <= 1;
```

See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/5459839) for several alternatives, also depending on your Oracle version.

Comment: Modern is modern ;)

Comment: Hi trincot, thank you...How to get highest version from versions?.

Comment: I added a reply to that in my answer.

Comment: I have data like as below:
COMPANY    Project   Version 
XXX        RBI       8.16.1.1 
XXX        RBI       8.16.1.2 
XXX        TAP       38.14.2.10 
XXX        TAP       38.14.2.9 
XXX  RB  8.0.4.185 
XXX  RB  8.0.4.174

need to get highest version from each project.?

Comment: The comments section is not suitable for follow-up questions. Please ask a new question. I will be happy to answer if you refer me to it.