# SQL Query for returning only 1 record with 2 conditions satisfied

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
 WHERE (ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'P')     -- 1
    OR (ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'J')     -- 2
```

Please help me with this piece of query. I need to show only the record with `CUST_FLAG = 'P'`. With the above Where clause I am getting both the records if both the conditions are satisfied.
My Requirement is:

1. If only 1st condition satisfies, then return the record with `CUST_FLAG = 'P'`
2. If only 2nd condition satisfies, then return the record with `CUST_FLAG = 'J'`
3. If both the conditions satisfies, then return only the record with `CUST_FLAG = 'P'`.

Comment: what "2nd condition"? You've got 4 different comparisons in there.

Comment: I meant the statements before and after OR.
ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'P' is 1
ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'J' is  2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  To do this in a single `where` clause, you can do:

```
WHERE ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND
      (CUST_FLAG = 'P' OR
       (CUST_FLAG = 'J' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE t.ADDR1 = outer.ADDR1 AND t.CUST_FLAG = 'J'
       ))
```

Or a more typical way is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by addr1 order by cust_flag desc) as seqnum
      from (<your query here>) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Or, to make the ORDER BY condition slightly less dependent on the accident of P and J:  `order by case cust_flag when 'P' then 0 when 'J' then 1 end` - at least that makes it crystal clear what the intent was.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around `case/when`

```
case 
  when ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'P' then 'P'
  when ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'J' then 'J'
  else 'P' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by sorting the records and only taking the first one. (But note that ROWNUM might by Oracle-specific syntax.)

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT <column_list> 
FROM <table>
WHERE ((ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'P')     -- 1
    OR (ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'J'))     -- 2
ORDER BY CUST_FLAG DESC
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Since Oracle 12c, the following syntax is also possible:

```
SELECT <column_list> 
FROM <table>
WHERE ((ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'P')     -- 1
    OR (ADDR1 = '1500 Valley Rd' AND CUST_FLAG = 'J'))     -- 2
ORDER BY CUST_FLAG DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

See also: 
 - [On ROWNUM and Limiting Results](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html)
 - [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)