# I want to get a SQL query for my asp.net

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

Here's the table:

```
firstname |lastname |Gender  | Age
fname1    |Lname1   | male   | 23
fname2    |Lname2   | male   | 22
fname3    |Lname3   | male   | 20
fname4    |Lname4   | female | 19
fname5    |Lname5   | female | 22
fname6    |Lname6   | female | 17
```

I want to select only 1 value such that when I set `gander = male` I should get the first and last name of the male with lowest age.

If I want to select the second lowest age person of `gender = male` I should also get that one, and similarly for female.

Comment: Add the expected result, as result-set, not as a description.

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a tie, i.e. two persons with the same lowest age?

Comment: there is no such possibilities that the user has same age

Comment: No users with same age??? Very odd. How do you prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Lowest

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE Gender='male' ORDER BY Age ASC LIMIT 0,1;
```

For Second Lowest

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE Gender='male' ORDER BY Age ASC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select firstname,lastname  from db where Gender = 'male' order by Age limit 1;
```

Comment: select firstname,lastname  from db where Gender = 'male' order by Age limit 1; Here it is showing  error that **  Incorrect syntax near 'limit'. **

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the second lowest use this:

```
SELECT firstname,lastname  FROM db WHERE Gender = 'male' ORDER BY Age LIMIT 1, 1;
```

LIMIT number_rows [ OFFSET offset_value ]
the second 1 after limit defines your offset to begin with.

LIMIT doesn't work for oracle (11).
In oracle-databases you need to create a temporary table with rowNumber column and perform selection by RowNum.

If you need it for oracle look at this post:
[Limit Number of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Comment: Newer Oracle versions also have `FETCH FIRST`, i.e. the ANSI SQL construction.