# How can I limit the amount of rows returned by an oracle query after ordering?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I know this is a duplicate question asked before but the other post doesn't solve my problem.

I am trying to display only the top 2 rows that result from the following query.

```
SELECT
    AVG(sessionprice),
    branchsuburb
FROM    branch,
        sessions
WHERE branch.branchid = sessions.branchid
GROUP BY branchsuburb
ORDER BY AVG(sessionprice) DESC;
```

That query as is will return all the results but I wish to restrict it to only the top 2 (in terms of which row has the highest average). I tried the fetch function in this post 
[How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) 
however it simply returns a ORA-00933 error. I know I must be making some silly mistake but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to do this without using a subquery?

The code after adding the fetch function looks like this

```
SELECT
    AVG(SESSIONPRICE),
    BRANCHSUBURB
FROM    BRANCH,
        SESSIONS
WHERE BRANCH.BRANCHID = SESSIONS.BRANCHID
GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: SQL Developer 4.1.5

Comment: Oracle version, not client version

Comment: Oracle database 11g

Comment: FETCH only exists from Oracle 12; Gordon's answer is what you need

Answer (score 6):

`FETCH` was recently introduced in Oracle.  In older versions, you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT bs.*
FROM (SELECT avg(sessionprice), branchsuburb
      FROM branch b JOIN
           sessions s
           ON b.branchid = s.branchid
      GROUP BY branchsuburb
      ORDER BY avg(sessionprice) DESC
     ) bs
WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there no way to do it without a subquery?

Comment: @Hayden null: No. You can move it to a cte as XING shows, but it stays a subquery. Or you can switch to Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE and achieve this;

```
with tbl as (SELECT avg(sessionprice), branchsuburb
              FROM branch b JOIN
                   sessions s
                   ON b.branchid = s.branchid
              GROUP BY branchsuburb
              ORDER BY avg(sessionprice) DESC )
select tbl.* from tbl
WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yon can try this. This is for pagination also with start and end position

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT inner_query.*, rownum rnum FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name) inner_query WHERE rownum <= 20) WHERE rnum >= 1;
```

Where **rownum** is no of records and **rnum** is for start position.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT
    AVG(SESSIONPRICE),
    BRANCHSUBURB
FROM    BRANCH,
        SESSIONS
WHERE BRANCH.BRANCHID = SESSIONS.BRANCHID
GROUP BY BRANCHSUBURB
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC ) where ROWID <= 2
```