# Select top two rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to display just the top two rows in Oracle, however I've not been able to come across anything that works.

I currently have

```
SELECT BRANCH.BRANCHID, BRANCHNAME, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM BRANCH, SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID = BRANCH.BRANCHID
GROUP BY BRANCHNAME, BRANCH.BRANCHID
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC
```

Which returns this

```
B2      A     18.67
B4      B     17.57
B3      C     15.44
B1      D     13.99
```

However, I only want the top two rows of this table.

How on earth do I do this?

Comment: `fetch first 2 rows only` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD

Comment: Have you tried [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)?

Comment: Yeah I have and I couldn't find a solution, I've only been learning SQL for like 2 weeks. So a lot of it I don't understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had edited answer again:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT BRANCH.BRANCHID, BRANCHNAME, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM BRANCH, SESSIONS
WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID = BRANCH.BRANCHID

GROUP BY BRANCHNAME, BRANCH.BRANCHID
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2;
```

Comment: This is not going to work properly. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, the edited one works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Special thanks to a_horse_with_no_name for his help.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 9i onwards, the RANK() and DENSE_RANK() functions can be used to determine the TOP N rows. Examples:

> Get the top 2 BRANCH using RANK()

```
SELECT ename, sal 
  FROM ( SELECT BRANCH.BRANCHID, BRANCHNAME, AVG(SESSIONPRICE) RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC) avg_rank
           FROM BRANCH) 
 WHERE avg_rank<= 2;
```

> Get the top 2 BRANCH using DENSE_RANK()

```
SELECT ename, sal 
  FROM ( SELECT BRANCH.BRANCHID, BRANCHNAME, AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC) avg_Dense_rank
           FROM BRANCH) 
 WHERE avg_Dense_rank<= 2;
```

Comment: Now I just get an error 'FROM Keyword not found where expected'

Comment: updated my ans check it now.

Answer (score -2):

Use RowNUM :

It is used to specify the number of records to return.

```
            SELECT BRANCH.BRANCHID, BRANCHNAME, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
            FROM BRANCH, SESSIONS
            WHERE 
            ROWNUM <= 2 and SESSIONS.BRANCHID = BRANCH.BRANCHID
            GROUP BY BRANCHNAME, BRANCH.BRANCHID
            ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC ;
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it changes the values in the third row. Would you know why it does that?