# SQL command not properly ended when using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am executing the below query in SQL Developer.

```
SELECT * FROM Person where person_name='rahul' order by created_time desc limit 10;
```

When I execute it, SQL Developer gives me below error.

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I used the below link for reference.

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php

I already tried

```
SELECT * FROM Person where person_name='rahul' order by created_time desc OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 75
```

Note that OFFSET is not treated as keyword.

Comment: Any change if you remove the ; ?

Comment: No. Still the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM Person where person_name='rahul' and rownum between 1 and 2 order by created_time desc;
```

Answer (score 27):

Yes, that' cause Oracle don't have or support `limit` clause and thus you are getting `ORA-00933` error. Rather, use `FETCH .. OFFSET` construct like

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
where person_name='rahul' 
order by created_time desc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

There are lot many similar question in StackOverflow. Should have tried searching the same. Example this one: [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering)

Answer (score 2):

If you get

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

It is probably because you aren't running Oracle 12. In that case, there are some workarounds, all involving subqueries and most sloppy. I used

```
select * from 
    ( select column_name, ROWNUM rnum from 
        ( select * from table_name) 
    where ROWNUM <= max_row )
where rnum  >= min_row order by column_name;
```

Comment: Note that becuase the `order by` is not in the inner most subquery it will only order the outermost subgroup. Basically if you have 1000 records, and you fetch 100-125, it will get a random set of 25 records and sort that. I think you want the `order by` after the `select * from table_name` part.